# How can I get onTouchEvent in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-gesture

In normal view, we can have `onTouchEvent`

```
    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        when (event?.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {}
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {}
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {}
            else -> return false
        }
        invalidate()
        return true
    }
```

In Jetpack Compose, I can only find we have the `tapGestureFilter` in the modifier, which only takes the action from the `ACTION_UP` only.

```
Modifier
    .tapGestureFilter { Log.d("Track", "Tap ${it.x} | ${it.y}") }
    .doubleTapGestureFilter { Log.d("Track", "DoubleTap ${it.x} | ${it.y}") }
```

Is there an equivalent `onTouchEvent` for Jetpack Compose?

Comment: Please let me know sth. Is it a bad practice to use the above function `onTouchEvent` in Jetpack compose project? I've tested it and it seems to function properly!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

We have a separate [package](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/pointer/package-summary) for that, which is pretty useful.
There are two main extension functions that would be suitable for you:

- `pointerInput` - [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/pointer/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).pointerInteropFilter(androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent,kotlin.Function1))
- `pointerInteropFilter` - [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/pointer/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).pointerInteropFilter(androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent,kotlin.Function1))

If you want to handle and process the event I recommend using `pointerInteropFilter` which is the analogue of `View.onTouchEvent`. It's used along with `modifier`:

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.pointerInteropFilter {
    when (it.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {}
        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {}
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {}
        else ->  false
    }
     true
})
```

That will be Compose adjusted code to your specified `View.onTouchEvent` sample.

P.S. Don't forget about `@ExperimentalPointerInput` annotation.

Comment: Nice, sweet! Testing `pointerInteropFilter`, works like a charm.

Comment: I didn't use `@ExperimentalPointerInput` though.. hmm, is that still needed?

Comment: @Elye Well, I'm using `androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.0.0-alpha05` and `pointerInput` requires ExperimentalPointerInput annotation. Maybe they will change some details, not sure. Glad to hear that it worked for you!

Comment: There is no `@ExperimentalPointerInput` in beta9, use `@ExperimentalComposeUiApi` instead

Comment: At Compose 1.1.0 is marked as `@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)`

Comment: This solution is not great because you can't trigger any gesture event of child views, So the trigger of child views depends on what you return after "when" statement (true or false), if you return false, children buttons trigger but you can't trigger this view's ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP afterwards. I'm search for solution where I can trigger both.

Comment: In my case this is exactly what I was looking for. I have a WebView call to Google Map from an AndroidView which I needed to block/cancel/ignore all click events, etc. so the user interaction is disabled. This won't let use the menus or  Buttons, etc. to exit the page or do other things.

Answer (score 28):

`pointerInteropFilter` is not described as preferred way to use if you are not using touch api with interoperation with existing View code.

> A special PointerInputModifier that provides access to the underlying
> MotionEvents originally dispatched to Compose. Prefer pointerInput and
> use this only for interoperation with existing code that consumes
> MotionEvents. While the main intent of this Modifier is to allow
> arbitrary code to access the original MotionEvent dispatched to
> Compose, for completeness, analogs are provided to allow arbitrary
> code to interact with the system as if it were an Android View.

You can use `pointerInput` , `awaitTouchDown` for  `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`, and `awaitPointerEvent` for `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`

```
val pointerModifier = Modifier
    .pointerInput(Unit) {
        awaitEachGesture {

            awaitFirstDown()
            // ACTION_DOWN here

            do {

                //This PointerEvent contains details including
                // event, id, position and more
                val event: PointerEvent = awaitPointerEvent()
                // ACTION_MOVE loop

                // Consuming event prevents other gestures or scroll to intercept
                event.changes.forEach { pointerInputChange: PointerInputChange ->
                    pointerInputChange.consumePositionChange()
                }
            } while (event.changes.any { it.pressed })

            // ACTION_UP is here


        }
    }
```

[image]

Some key notes about gestures

1. pointerInput propagation is when you have more than one goes from
   bottom one to top one.
2. If children and parent are listening for input changes it propagates
   from inner children to outer then parent. Unlike touch events from
   parent to children
   ***( This is true for PointerEventPass.Main, PointerEventPass.Final or PointerEventPass.Initial changes propagation direction)***
3. If you don't consume events other events like scroll drag can
   interfere or consume events, most of the events check if it's
   consumed before propagating to them

detectDragGestures source code for instance

```
val down = awaitFirstDown(requireUnconsumed = false)
    var drag: PointerInputChange?
    var overSlop = Offset.Zero
    do {
        drag = awaitPointerSlopOrCancellation(
            down.id,
            down.type
        ) { change, over ->
            change.consumePositionChange()
            overSlop = over
        }
    } while (drag != null && !drag.positionChangeConsumed())
```

4. So when you need to prevent other events to intercept

   call `pointerInputChange.consumeDown()` after `awaitFirstDown`, call
   pointerInputChange.consumePositionChange() after `awaitPointerEvent`

   and `awaitFirstDown()` has `requireUnconsumed` parameter which is
   true by default. If you set it to false even if a pointerInput consumes
   down before your gesture you still get it. This is also how events like drag use it to get first down no matter what.
5. Every available event you see `detectDragGestures`,
   `detectTapGestures` even `awaitFirstDown` use `awaitPointerEvent`
   for implementation, so using `awaitFirstDown`, `awaitPointerEvent`
   and **consuming changes** you can configure your own gestures.

For instance, this is a function  i customized from original `detectTransformGestures` only to be invoked with specific number of pointers down.

```
suspend fun PointerInputScope.detectMultiplePointerTransformGestures(
    panZoomLock: Boolean = false,
    numberOfPointersRequired: Int = 2,
    onGesture: (centroid: Offset, pan: Offset, zoom: Float, rotation: Float) -> Unit,

    ) {
    forEachGesture {
        awaitPointerEventScope {
            var rotation = 0f
            var zoom = 1f
            var pan = Offset.Zero
            var pastTouchSlop = false
            val touchSlop = viewConfiguration.touchSlop
            var lockedToPanZoom = false

            awaitFirstDown(requireUnconsumed = false)

            do {
                val event = awaitPointerEvent()

                val downPointerCount = event.changes.size

                // If any position change is consumed from another pointer or pointer
                // count that is pressed is not equal to pointerCount cancel this gesture
                val canceled = event.changes.any { it.positionChangeConsumed() } || (
                        downPointerCount != numberOfPointersRequired)

                if (!canceled) {
                    val zoomChange = event.calculateZoom()
                    val rotationChange = event.calculateRotation()
                    val panChange = event.calculatePan()

                    if (!pastTouchSlop) {
                        zoom *= zoomChange
                        rotation += rotationChange
                        pan += panChange

                        val centroidSize = event.calculateCentroidSize(useCurrent = false)
                        val zoomMotion = abs(1 - zoom) * centroidSize
                        val rotationMotion =
                            abs(rotation * PI.toFloat() * centroidSize / 180f)
                        val panMotion = pan.getDistance()

                        if (zoomMotion > touchSlop ||
                            rotationMotion > touchSlop ||
                            panMotion > touchSlop
                        ) {
                            pastTouchSlop = true
                            lockedToPanZoom = panZoomLock && rotationMotion < touchSlop
                        }
                    }

                    if (pastTouchSlop) {
                        val centroid = event.calculateCentroid(useCurrent = false)
                        val effectiveRotation = if (lockedToPanZoom) 0f else rotationChange
                        if (effectiveRotation != 0f ||
                            zoomChange != 1f ||
                            panChange != Offset.Zero
                        ) {
                            onGesture(centroid, panChange, zoomChange, effectiveRotation)
                        }
                        event.changes.forEach {
                            if (it.positionChanged()) {
                                it.consumeAllChanges()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } while (!canceled && event.changes.any { it.pressed })
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit

As of **1.2.0-beta01**, partial consumes like
`PointerInputChange.consemePositionChange()`,
`PointerInputChange.consumeDownChange()`, and one for consuming all changes `PointerInputChange.consumeAllChanges()` are deprecated

```
PointerInputChange.consume()
```

is the only one to be used preventing other gestures/event.

Also i have a [tutorial here](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials#gesture) that covers gestures in detail

Comment: Is there also a way to allow zooming (pinch) out of a layout that contains a clickable areas? i can drag this layout around, but when wanting to pinch, it just presses the buttons.

Comment: You can chain multiple `Modifier.pointerInput`s the last one being for detecting transform gestures. And other option is to use Final PointerEventPass instead of Main. Would you mind asking this as a separate question with some code or some visuals?

Comment: Did that, hope it's more clear here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75955466

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a bit late, but since compose is constantly updating, this is how I do it as of today:

```
Modifier
    .pointerInput(Unit) {
        detectTapGestures {...}
     }
    .pointerInput(Unit) {
        detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->  ...}
    })
```

We also have `detectHorizontalDragGestures` and `detectVerticalDragGestures` among others to help us.

ps: `1.0.0-beta03`

Answer (score 3):

Compose `PointerEventType.Press`, `.Move` and `.Release` correspond closely to View `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`, `_MOVE` and `_UP`  respectively. (See the Android platform implementation file PointerEvent.android.kt for the mapping to `PointerEvent.type`.)

You can extend `PointerInputScope` with a function that takes three lambda parameters and routes the events to the intended one.

In the following example, it is assumed that multiple pointers are handled in the lambdas.

```
suspend fun PointerInputScope.routePointerChangesTo(
    onDown: (PointerInputChange) -> Unit = {},
    onMove: (PointerInputChange) -> Unit = {},
    onUp: (PointerInputChange) -> Unit = {}
) {
    awaitEachGesture {
        do {
            val event = awaitPointerEvent()
            event.changes.forEach {
                when (event.type) {
                    PointerEventType.Press -> onDown(it)
                    PointerEventType.Move -> onMove(it)
                    PointerEventType.Release -> onUp(it)
                }
                it.consume()
            }
        } while (event.changes.any { it.pressed })
    }
}
```

Test it by calling with a `Modifier` like this on a `Composable`:

```
    Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
        routePointerChangesTo(
            onDown = { change -> println("Down at ${change.position}")},
            onMove = { change -> println("Move to ${change.position}")},
            onUp = { change -> println("Up at ${change.position}")}
        )
    }
```

If you are fine with `onDown()` only being called once the touch slop has been exceeded, you can simply use the `detectDragGestures()` function on `PointerInputScope` to achieve a similar result.

If pointers other than the first down should be ignored, it becomes a little more complicated:

```
suspend fun PointerInputScope.routePointerChangesTo(
    onDown: (PointerInputChange) -> Unit = {},
    onMove: (PointerInputChange) -> Unit = {},
    onUp: (PointerInputChange) -> Unit = {}
) {
    awaitEachGesture {
        awaitFirstDown().let { firstDownChange ->
            onDown(firstDownChange)
            firstDownChange.consume()
            var isFirstPointerDown = true
            do {
                awaitPointerEvent().let { event ->
                    event.changes.forEach { change ->
                        if (change.id == firstDownChange.id) {
                            when (event.type) {
                                PointerEventType.Move -> {
                                    onMove(change)
                                    change.consume()
                                }
                                PointerEventType.Release -> {
                                    if (!change.pressed) {
                                        isFirstPointerDown = false
                                        onUp(change)
                                        change.consume()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } while (isFirstPointerDown)
        }
    }
}
```

See also [this guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/touch-input/pointer-input/understand-gestures) for a video and more snippets using `pointerInput`.

Answer (score 0):

After did some research, looks like can use `dragGestureFilter`, mixed with `tapGestureFilter`

```
Modifier
    .dragGestureFilter(object: DragObserver {
        override fun onDrag(dragDistance: Offset): Offset {
            Log.d("Track", "onActionMove ${dragDistance.x} | ${dragDistance.y}")
            return super.onDrag(dragDistance)
        }
        override fun onStart(downPosition: Offset) {
            Log.d("Track", "onActionDown ${downPosition.x} | ${downPosition.y}")
            super.onStart(downPosition)
        }
        override fun onStop(velocity: Offset) {
            Log.d("Track", "onStop ${velocity.x} | ${velocity.y}")
            super.onStop(velocity)
        }
    }, { true })
    .tapGestureFilter {
        Log.d("NGVL", "onActionUp ${it.x} | ${it.y}")
    }
```

The reason still use `tagGestureFilter`, is because the `onStop` doesn't provide the position, but just the velocity, hence the `tapGestureFilter` does help provide the last position (if needed)