# How to move zoom image in LazyColumn?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm working on a PDF reader in Jetpack Compose Android and I am new to gesture and touch events.

I have a list of images in LazyColumn, and I've used pinch in/out and double tapping to add zoom capability to each item. However, once I zoom in, I'm unable to move the image.

Additionally, I would like to keep the scroll behaviour. I used zoom reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69324882/zoom-lazycolumn-item) & [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76937896/zooming-each-image-inside-lazycolumn-causes-content-to-overlap).

Any help would be helpful. Thank you

[image]

Here is my effort.

```
    @OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun Render2(file: File) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        val pdfRender = PdfRender(file)

        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            items(count = pdfRender.pdfRenderer.pageCount) { index ->
                val page = pdfRender.pageLists[index]
                LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
                    page.load()
                }
                page.pageContent.collectAsState().value?.asImageBitmap()?.let {
                    Image(
                        contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .background(Color.White)
                            .aspectRatio(1f / sqrt(2f))
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .clipToBounds()
                            .combinedClickable(
                                interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                                indication = null,
                                onClick = {},
                                onDoubleClick = {
                                    page.scale = if (page.scale > 1f) 1f
                                    else 3f
                                }
                            )
                            .graphicsLayer {
                                scaleX = page.scale
                                scaleY = page.scale
                            }
                            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                                forEachGesture {
                                    awaitPointerEventScope {
                                        // Wait for at least one pointer to press down
                                        awaitFirstDown()
                                        do {

                                            val event = awaitPointerEvent()
                                            // Calculate gestures and consume pointerInputChange
                                            // only size of pointers down is 2
                                            if (event.changes.size == 2) {
                                                var zoom = page.scale
                                                zoom *= event.calculateZoom()
                                                // Limit zoom between 100% and 300%
                                                zoom = zoom.coerceIn(1f, 3f)
                                                page.scale = zoom

                                                event.changes.forEach { pointerInputChange: PointerInputChange ->
                                                    pointerInputChange.consume()
                                                }
                                            }
                                        } while (event.changes.any { it.pressed })
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        bitmap = it,
                        contentDescription = "Pdf page number: $index"
                    )
                }
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for `clipToBounds()` *before* image manipulations!