# Kotlin Jetpack Compose DragGesture property cancel the scrolling of my View

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, draggable, swipe, gesture

I'am new to jetpack compose and i really liked it. But ran into a problem : I want know if my view is swiped up or down so i created a LazyColumn with some item in it to be able to scroll something. It work fine but i would like to access the Gesture property to know if the view is scrolled down or up, here is my code :

```
LazyColumn{
            items (100){
                Text(
                    text = "Item $it",
                    fontSize = 24.sp,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .padding(vertical = 24.dp)
                        .pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                            //change.consumeAllChanges()// i don't know if this does something, i tried to remove it
                            println("detectDragGestures")
                            val (x, y) = dragAmount
                            if(abs(x) < abs(y)){
                                if (y > 0)
                                    println("drag down")
                                else
                                    println("drag Up")
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
```

This work, i can detect if the view is scrolled down or up, the problem is when i tap on the item and scroll, i get the right print but the view isn't scrolled, i have to click between item to be able to scroll.

I don't really know how gesture work in jetpack compose but i would like to get the direction of the swipe without preventing my view to be scrolled.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to detect scroll direction with using Column instead of LazyColumn.

I hope it can lead you.

```
@Composable
fun ScrollDetect() {
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    var dragPosition by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = scrollState.value, block = {
        if (scrollState.value > dragPosition)
            Log.e("dragging", "up")
        else
            Log.e("dragging", "down")
        dragPosition = scrollState.value

    })
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .verticalScroll(scrollState)
    )
    {
        repeat(100) {
            Text(
                text = "Item $it",
                fontSize = 24.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(vertical = 24.dp)

            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Explanation of  how gesture system in Jetpack Compose works in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64571945/how-can-i-get-ontouchevent-in-jetpack-compose/70847531#70847531) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72774367/multiple-different-pointerinput/72775597#72775597)

`change.consumeAllChanges()` is deprecated now, partial consumes are deprecated. `change.consume()` is the only consume function to be used. What consume does is it returns `change.isConsumed` **true** and because of that any drag, scroll, transform gesture stops progressing or receiving events. detectDragGestures and detectTransformGestures consume events by default so next

`Modifier.pointerInput()` doesn't get these events. What you commented doesn't mean anything since drag already consumes events.

Here it's source code.

```
suspend fun PointerInputScope.detectDragGestures(
    onDragStart: (Offset) -> Unit = { },
    onDragEnd: () -> Unit = { },
    onDragCancel: () -> Unit = { },
    onDrag: (change: PointerInputChange, dragAmount: Offset) -> Unit
) {
    forEachGesture {
        awaitPointerEventScope {
            val down = awaitFirstDown(requireUnconsumed = false)
            var drag: PointerInputChange?
            var overSlop = Offset.Zero
            do {
                drag = awaitPointerSlopOrCancellation(
                    down.id,
                    down.type
                ) { change, over ->
                    change.consume()
                    overSlop = over
                }
            // ! EVERY Default movable GESTURE HAS THIS CHECK
            } while (drag != null && !drag.isConsumed)
            if (drag != null) {
                onDragStart.invoke(drag.position)
                onDrag(drag, overSlop)
                if (
                    !drag(drag.id) {
                        onDrag(it, it.positionChange())
                        it.consume()
                    }
                ) {
                    onDragCancel()
                } else {
                    onDragEnd()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What you can do is using **nestedScroll** on parent of LazyColumn as here

```
@Composable
private fun NestedScrollExample() {

    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }


    val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
        object : NestedScrollConnection {

            override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
                text = "onPreScroll()\n" +
                        "available: $available\n" +
                        "source: $source\n\n"
                return super.onPreScroll(available, source)
            }

            override fun onPostScroll(
                consumed: Offset,
                available: Offset,
                source: NestedScrollSource
            ): Offset {
                text += "onPostScroll()\n" +
                        "consumed: $consumed\n" +
                        "available: $available\n" +
                        "source: $source\n\n"
                return super.onPostScroll(consumed, available, source)
            }

            override suspend fun onPreFling(available: Velocity): Velocity {
                text += "onPreFling()\n" +
                        " available: $available\n\n"
                return super.onPreFling(available)
            }

            override suspend fun onPostFling(consumed: Velocity, available: Velocity): Velocity {
                text += "onPostFling()\n" +
                        "consumed: $consumed\n" +
                        "available: $available\n\n"
                return super.onPostFling(consumed, available)
            }
        }
    }

    Column() {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
        ) {
            LazyColumn(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
            ) {
                items(100) {
                    Text(
                        text = "I'm item $it",
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .shadow(1.dp, RoundedCornerShape(5.dp))
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .background(Color.LightGray)
                            .padding(12.dp),
                        fontSize = 16.sp,
                        color = Color.White
                    )
                }
            }
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Text(
            text = text,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .height(250.dp)
                .padding(10.dp)
                .background(BlueGrey400),
            fontSize = 16.sp,
            color = Color.White
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

It will return if you scroll up or down on your LazyColumn, if you want to do this only when your items are being scrolled you can do it as

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("Drag to see effects") }
    Text(text)

    LazyColumn {
        items(100) {
            Text(
                text = "Item $it",
                fontSize = 24.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .border(3.dp, Color.Green)
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(vertical = 24.dp)
                    .pointerMotionEvents(Unit,
                        onDown = {
                                 it.consume()
                        },

                        onMove = { change ->
                            val position = change.positionChange()

                            val dragText = if (position.y < 0) {
                                "drag up"
                            } else if (position.y > 0) {
                                "drag down"
                            } else {
                                "idle"
                            }

                            text = "position: ${change.position}\n" +
                                    "positionChange: ${change.positionChange()}\n" +
                                    "dragText: $dragText"
                        }
                    )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Modifier.pointerMotionEvents() is a gesture Modifier i wrote, it's available [here](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Extended-Gestures).