# How can i use multiple gesture in the same Android Compose View?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, gesture

I would like to use drag and tap gestures in the same view.

```
 Canvas(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                                detectTapGestures(
                                    onDoubleTap = {
                                        Log.i("Double Tap","Clicked")
                                    }
                                )

                                detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                                    change.consumeAllChanges()
                                    dragAmountX = dragAmount.x
                                    dragAmountY = dragAmount.y
                                }
                            }
                    )
```

I tried this way but only tap gesture is working.
How can i use tap and drag gesture at the same time in a view ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to chain them as in answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72774367/multiple-different-pointerinput/72775597#72775597).

```
Modifier
  .pointerInput(keys){
    
  } 
  .pointerInput(keys){
   

  }
```

And `change.consumeAllChanges()` is deprecated as of 1.2.0-beta01 it's `change.consume()`. What consume() does is it prevents continuous gestures like drag, transform or scroll to receiving events because all the gestures above check `change.isConsumed` `true` before looping event.

```
val context = LocalContext.current

val modifier = Modifier
    .pointerInput(Unit) {
        detectTapGestures(
            onPress = {
                Toast
                    .makeText(context, "onPress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            },
            onTap = {
                Toast
                    .makeText(context, "onTap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            }
        )
    }

    .pointerInput(Unit) {
        detectDragGestures(
            onDragStart = {
                Toast
                    .makeText(context, "onDragStart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
            },
            onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                println("DRAGGING $dragAmount")

            }
        )
    }
```

Let me add as side note as answer in the link. `detectGestures` call `change.consume()` just after it invokes `onDrag()` callback. Because of that unless you do some conditional event check inside `onDrag()`  calling `consume.change()` is useless. When a `PointerInputChange` is consumed `PointerInputChange.positionChange()` returns Offset.Zero and PointerInputChange.isConsumed true.

```
private fun PointerInputChange.positionChangeInternal(ignoreConsumed: Boolean = false): Offset {
    val previousPosition = previousPosition
    val currentPosition = position

    val offset = currentPosition - previousPosition

    return if (!ignoreConsumed && isConsumed) Offset.Zero else offset
}
```