# How to make long press for custom seconds?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, long-press

I would like to create `Button` with long press for 7 seconds in `Jetpack Compose`.
How to customize `onLongPress` click?

If user long press button for 4 seconds it won't work. It needs 7 seconds to make action.

Comment: You can refer this answer. It has customization for time duration that returns boolean true when time has passed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73419818/5457853.