# How to check at pointerinput if longpress ended?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

how can I check when the gesture onlongpress ended?
Anything like gestureUp or gestureEnd?

```
Card(colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
            containerColor = Color(0xFF7DCEA0), Color.Black
        ),
            elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(defaultElevation = 2.dp),
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(horizontal = 6.dp, vertical = 6.dp)
                .offset { IntOffset(swipeableState.offset.value.roundToInt(), 0) }
                .pointerInput(Unit){
                     detectTapGestures(
                         onLongPress = {
                            
                             mContext.startActivity(Intent(mContext, DCInfo::class.java))
                         }
                     )
                }
                .border(1.dp, SolidColor(Color(0xFF1C536F)), shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp))
                .fillMaxWidth(), shape = RoundedCornerShape(CornerSize(15.dp))
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by adding callbacks to implementation of press and long press by writing your own PointerInputScope function.

Explained in detail [how it works here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70847531/5457853), you can check out if you are interested in details.

```
suspend fun PointerInputScope.detectPressGestures(
    onLongPress: ((Offset) -> Unit)? = null,
    onPressStart: ((Offset) -> Unit)? = null,
    onPressEnd: (() -> Unit)? = null,
    onLongPressEnd: (() -> Unit)? = null,
) = coroutineScope {

    awaitEachGesture {
        val down = awaitFirstDown()
        down.consume()

        val downTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        onPressStart?.invoke(down.position)

        val longPressTimeout = onLongPress?.let {
            viewConfiguration.longPressTimeoutMillis
        } ?: (Long.MAX_VALUE / 2)

        var longPressInvoked = false

        do {
            val event: PointerEvent = awaitPointerEvent()
            val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

            if (!longPressInvoked && currentTime - downTime >= longPressTimeout) {
                onLongPress?.invoke(event.changes.first().position)
                longPressInvoked = true
            }

            event.changes
                .forEach { pointerInputChange: PointerInputChange ->
                    pointerInputChange.consume()
                }


        } while (event.changes.any { it.pressed })

        if (longPressInvoked) {
            onLongPressEnd?.invoke()
        } else {
            onPressEnd?.invoke()
        }

    }
}
```

Call it inside `Modifier.pointerInput(){}` as

```
Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
    detectPressGestures(
        onPressStart = {
        },
        onLongPress = {
        },
        onLongPressEnd = {
        },
        onPressEnd = {
        }
    )
}
```

Full implementation and demo to show color changes on events.

[image]

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun PressCallbacks() {
    var gestureColor by remember { mutableStateOf(Color.LightGray) }
    val context = LocalContext.current

    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .size(200.dp)
        .background(gestureColor)
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectPressGestures(
                onPressStart = {
                    gestureColor = Color.Yellow
                    Toast
                        .makeText(
                            context,
                            "Press Start",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        )
                        .show()
                },
                onLongPress = {
                    gestureColor = Color.Blue
                    Toast
                        .makeText(
                            context,
                            "Long Press!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        )
                        .show()

                },
                onLongPressEnd = {
                    gestureColor = Color.Black
                    Toast
                        .makeText(
                            context,
                            "Long Press ENDS",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        )
                        .show()
                },
                onPressEnd = {
                    Toast
                        .makeText(
                            context,
                            "Press ENDS",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        )
                        .show()
                    gestureColor = Color.Cyan
                }
            )
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not what you are looking for but you with the `onPress` event you can use something like:

```
enum class ComponentState { Pressed, Released }

var toState by remember { mutableStateOf(ComponentState.Released) }
LaunchedEffect(toState){
    if (toState == ComponentState.Released){
        //doSomething()
    }
}

Card(
    //...
    modifier = Modifier
       //...
      .pointerInput(Unit) {
         detectTapGestures(
            onPress = {
                toState = ComponentState.Pressed
                tryAwaitRelease()
                toState = ComponentState.Released
            },
        )

){
  //...
}
```