# Jetpack Compose Android Button detect long click

Tags: android, kotlin, button, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

How to detect a long click

```
    Button(
    onClick = onClick,
    interactionSource = interactionSource,
    modifier = Modifier
        .combinedClickable(
            onClick = onClick,
            onLongClick = onLongClick
        )
)
```

This doesn't work. onClick is required and I guess it consumes combinedClickable. I also need an interactionSource.
I would rather prefer to avoid create a custom button.

Comment: Works for me. Try putting some brackets around your functions, like: ```onLongClick = { onLongClick }```? Not sure if that would help...

Comment: I've added just logs for an action. And still I got only an event from main onClick. combinedClickable does nothing.

Comment: Note that as of this comment, combinedClickable is experimental:
"combinedClickable is an experimental API, which means the API surface might change in a future release of Compose. However, the modifier's behavior is considered stable."
In my experience 'Google considered stable' != production stable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It won't work with `Button` because of the same reason you can't chain `Modifier.clickable{}.clickable{}`

With `Button` adding another `Modifier.pointerInput()` won't have any effect because `Button` is a `Surface` with onClick param that is assigned `Modifier.clickable()` already. `Modifier.clickable` already consumes events and not letting other `Modifier.pointerInput()` receiving it.

In Jetpack Compose when there are two or more `Modifier.pointerInput()` chained together the one at the bottom receives event first with default **pass** which is`PointeEventPass.Main`. Since, clickable already consumes, the one you assign will never get it.

Simplest way is to use InteractionSource and collecting it as

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun ButtonLongClickSample() {

    val context = LocalContext.current

    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }

    val viewConfiguration = LocalViewConfiguration.current


    LaunchedEffect(interactionSource) {
        var isLongClick = false

        interactionSource.interactions.collectLatest { interaction ->
            when (interaction) {
                is PressInteraction.Press -> {
                    isLongClick = false
                    delay(viewConfiguration.longPressTimeoutMillis)
                    isLongClick = true
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Long click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                is PressInteraction.Release -> {
                    if (isLongClick.not()) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }


    Button(
        onClick = {},
        interactionSource = interactionSource
    ) {
        Text("Some button")
    }
}
```

Comment: Other option even if it's unnecessary, if you wish to have long press with `Button` is to write your own press and long press gesture, Modifier.combinedClickable is detectTrapGestures under the hood with PointerEventPass.Initial. I posted similar answer for transform gestures here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75955466/jetpack-compose-intercept-pinch-zoom-in-child-layout

Comment: I've tried to use Box and Sufrace, but interactionSource seems not working with it. I need to have an access to press state in order to change some colours.

Comment: The long click detection works as expected with the suggested `interactionSource` approach on `material3:1.1.2` and is currently the only one working I found with the `Button` component directly. Thanks @Thracian!

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

```
 modifier = Modifier
           .weight(2f)
           .pointerInput(Unit){
               detectTapGestures(
                     onLongPress = {
                             // perform some action here..
                     }
               )
            }
```

Comment: I've already tried this. Still every action goes to main onClick.

Comment: This is not working for a `Button` element because `onClick` seems to override all the `detectTapGestures()`. Also using that code on a wrapper of the `Button` does not work and the button's `onClick` is executed.