# Android Compose why does Checkbox need onCheckChanged when parent is clickable?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-gesture

I am trying to have a checkbox with some trailing text. The idea is that whether you select the checkbox itself, or the text, the value is toggled. For brevity in code I've done everything in the composable.

It works as expected when selecting the text. But when I specifically press the checkbox, nothing happens. I see the ripple effect from pressing the checkbox but it is obviously ignoring the row's clickable function and hitting `onCheckChange = {}`

I'm not entirely fluent in composable scopes so I thought it might be due to `Row()` being an inline function so I tried applying the same modifier to the `Surface` but that doesn't work either.

It isn't a big deal having the same call from the 2 spots, I would just like to know why.

```
@Composable
fun CheckboxInRowWithText() {
    var checkedState by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Surface {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .clickable {
                    checkedState = !checkedState
                },
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            Checkbox(checked = checkedState, onCheckedChange = {} )

            Text(text = "Clicking this Row will toggle checkbox")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you can't click an ancestor Composable is not because it's under another, touch propagation goes from descendant to ancestor by default because of PointerEventPass which is Main.

The reason Modifier.clickable doesn't allow parent to get event is, it calls `PointerEventChange.consume` but you can write your own click functions to propagate from child to parent or parent to child or consume conditionally.

You can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70847531/5457853) for more details

You are basically doing nothing on checkBoxChange that's why it doesn't change, set checkedState inside `onCheckedChange`.

```
@Composable
fun CheckboxInRowWithText() {

    val context = LocalContext.current

    var checkedState by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Surface {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .clickable {
                    Toast
                        .makeText(context, "Row clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                    checkedState = !checkedState
                },
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            Checkbox(checked = checkedState, onCheckedChange = {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Checkbox check", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                checkedState = it
            }
            )

            Text(text = "Clicking this Row will toggle checkbox")
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can build it like this which will show ripple even when you click CheckBox.

```
@Composable
 fun CheckBoxWithTextRippleFullRow(
    label: String,
    state: Boolean,
    onStateChange: (Boolean) -> Unit
) {

    // Checkbox with text on right side
    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(40.dp)
        .clickable(
            role = Role.Checkbox,
            onClick = {
                onStateChange(!state)
            }
        )
        .padding(8.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Checkbox(
            checked = state,
            onCheckedChange = null
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
        Text(text = label)
    }
}
```

Result

[image]

### Click propagation sample

You can click below a Composable even with a `Button` which is a `Surface` with `Modifier.clickable` under the hood.

Let's create our own custom touch only for the parent below `Button`

```
private fun Modifier.customTouch(
    pass: PointerEventPass,
    onDown: () -> Unit,
    onUp: () -> Unit
) = this.then(
    Modifier.pointerInput(pass) {
        awaitEachGesture {
            awaitFirstDown(pass = pass)
            onDown()
            waitForUpOrCancellation(pass)
            onUp()
        }
    }
)
```

And assign it to parent with PointerEventPass.Initial with no consume call and will result as

[image]

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun GesturePropagationTest() {

    val context = LocalContext.current

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .customTouch(
                pass = PointerEventPass.Initial,
                onDown = {
                    Toast
                        .makeText(context, "Parent down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                }, onUp = {
                    Toast
                        .makeText(context, "Parent up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                }
            )
            .padding(bottom = 50.dp)
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(20.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }) {
            Text("Click Button")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer Thracian. Plenty for me to dive into from this, have a good day.

Comment: You are welcome. Touch system in Compose is pretty straightforward, when you read some documentation and create some samples it's not that difficult to overcome any custom gesture needs or understand why you can't drag or detect transform gestures do not work with scroll  or some callbacks are not  invoked. If you need to change direction change pass, if you need some child or parent not to react some touch event consume, that's it.

Comment: I just noticed I have your Compose course project starred and have actually used it recently so quite funny you are the one answering ! Small world

Comment: Thanks for your support, you can check out gesture tutorials that shows every step about gestures in some degree of isolation to show effect of propagation, consume, indications and so on. After grasping the basics with consume and propgation and `awaitFirstDown` and `awaintPointerEvent` everything about gesture will be like piece of cake and when you inspect source code of any gesture you will see why it doesn't work in combination with another

Answer (score 0):

Children are simply drawn on top of their parent container, that's the only way it makes sense. If you set background to that `Checkbox`, you'd expect it to cover background of the `Row`, no? It's same with clicking. You can't click on something that's **below** other clickable element. It's the same for Compose and View system.

Comment: This answer contains incorrect information. The reason you can't propagate gesture or click from child to parent `Modifier.clickable` is it propagates from child to parent and it consumes PointerEventChange. You can click or pass any gesture from one to another in direction you prefer by changing PointeEventPass and not consuming via Modifier.pointerInput and implementing your own click gesture. `Modifier.clickable` is also Modifier.pointerInput under the hood.