# How to get MotionEvent touch size from PointerInputScope low level approach?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

With Compose, We can get screen finger size by means of Modifier.pointerInteropFilter approach,
catching the MotionEvent property size. Officially, that is not recommended.
On the other hand, I haven't found a way to get exactly the same MotionEvent size value
with the suggested PointerInputScope avaliable in Modifier.pointerInput() call.
That scope gives us access to size property, which is very different from the MoveEvent homonym (I think the whole touchable area).
Is it possible to get the same value from Modifier.pointerInput()?

I mean, getting MotionvEnt a get a expected value:

`    @Composable
fun ProductsList(){

```
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .pointerInteropFilter() { // here it's a MotionEvent!
                val touchSize = it.size // <- :) good!
                //... 
                false
            } ){//...}
}`
```

While with PonterInputScope, the closest I found:

`    @Composable
fun ProductsList(){

```
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .pointerInput(filter) { // here it's PointerInputScope!
                val touchSize = size // <- :/ ? actually, an IntSize object
            }){//...}
}`
```

Can I get the same touch size value using pointerInput?

Answer (score 0):

You can get `val event: PointerEvent = awaitPointerEvent()` which contains
changes, buttons and some other info about current state of gestures.

event.changes returns list of pointers as

```
val pointerInputChangeList: List<PointerInputChange> = event.changes
```

And you can get many information about PointerInputChange including if they are pressed, released, touch time, etc.

You can refer answer about pointerInput in detail answer below

[How can I get onTouchEvent in Jetpack Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64571945/how-can-i-get-ontouchevent-in-jetpack-compose/70847531#70847531)

or snippet about touch loop

```
val pointerModifier = Modifier
    .pointerInput(Unit) {
        awaitEachGesture {

            awaitFirstDown()
            // ACTION_DOWN here

            do {

                //This PointerEvent contains details including
                // event, id, position and more
                val event: PointerEvent = awaitPointerEvent()
                // ACTION_MOVE loop

                // Consuming event prevents other gestures or scroll to intercept
                event.changes.forEach { pointerInputChange: PointerInputChange ->
                    pointerInputChange.consume()
                }
            } while (event.changes.any { it.pressed })

            // ACTION_UP is here


        }
    }
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, bro, but none of the these values returned by event.changes match with MotionEvent.size. If I am not wrong.

Comment: What does this size value in pointerOpFilter mean exactly? What's ` screen finger size`?

Comment: According to official doc: "Returns a scaled value of the approximate size for the given pointer index (use getPointerId(int) to find the pointer identifier for this index). This represents some approximation of the area of the screen being pressed; the actual value in pixels corresponding to the touch is normalized with the device specific range of values and scaled to a value between 0 and 1. The value of size can be used to determine fat touch events.". https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#getSize(int)