Android Drag & Drop for reordering lists detectDragGesturesAfterLongPress shorten long press wait
I have used a google sample app to implement list reording in my compose lazycolumn list and it all works fine.
the issue i have is that this implementation empoys detectDragGesturesAfterLongPress
which makes reordering the list quite slow and tedious. i would like to be ablt to implement someting like detectDragGesturesAfterTap or detectDragGesturesAfterShortPress
i tried using detectDragGestures which appears to be very "hit and miss" and only really consistently worked for the first drag and drop.
is there an approach where my users do not have to long press a list item before it becomes active in a drag and drop action?
how can i configure the time the "long press" takes?
this is the code i am using currently
fun Modifier.dragContainer(dragDropState: DragDropState): Modifier = then(this)
    .pointerInput(dragDropState) {
        detectDragGesturesAfterLongPress(
            onDrag = { change, offset ->
                change.consume()
                dragDropState.onDrag(offset = offset)
            },
            onDragStart = { offset -> dragDropState.onDragStart(offset) },
            onDragEnd = { dragDropState.onDragInterrupted() },
            onDragCancel = { dragDropState.onDragInterrupted() }
        )
    }


If you want drag gesture to start immediately after first pointer is moved you can check this answer which is how you implement down, move or drag loop and up when last pointer is up. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70847531/5457853

You can't modify the duration it takes to fire the onLongPress event, as this is defined by the Android OS. You can globally change that in the accessibility settings, but not within the app itself.
 | 
It would not make sense to override this, as someone might intentionally set the long press duration to "long" for their device, to avoid accidental inputs. Your app would become unusable for them.
Something like detectDragGesturesAfterTap or detectDragGesturesAfterShortPress doesn't exist, as these would actually be registered as a swipe, which is consumed to scroll the LazyColumn.
If your LazyColumn heavily relies on reordering, I would recommend to add a drag handle to each list item instead. If the user starts dragging while being above the handle, it can then immediately reorder instead of triggering a scroll event. This is also depicted in the material3 guidlines:


adding a drag handle does not address how long my users have to press and wait before they can commence the drag action though

My thought was that you can try to use detectDragGestures on the drag handle icon. Then the users still can regularly scroll, only when they exactly touch the drag target, they can immediately drag it. I don't know how what you meant by "hit and miss", I thought you meant that sometimes the drag is consumed as scroll and sometimes not.

"hit and miss" meaning... the majority of the time nothing happended when i click on a list item,

Drag gesture uses  awaitTouchSlopOrCancellation which requires user to drag till threshold if that's what you mean @Hector. Also drag always calls PointerEvent.consume. Unless you write your custom gesture that uses different PointerEventPass other than with Mainwhich is default pass drag will always intercept other gestures @BenjyTec
