How do I make Jetpack Compose HorizontalPager swipe forward only (disable backward swipe)?
On Android using Jetpack Compose, I want to make the HorizontalPager scroll in only one direction, so forward only. I can’t get either pointerInput or pointerInteropFilter to correctly handle my gesture detection.
I've tried the following code, but neither option works
 // if you use detectDragGesture on the box, then the message is printed, however the event does not bubble up and the horizontalPager will not swipe
  // if you put the pointerInput onto the HorizontalPager, then the gesture is not detected and no message is printed
  HorizontalPager(state = pagerState) { page ->
        // Display each page with a different background color
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(colors[page])
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectDragGestures { _, _ ->
                        println("In Here")
                    }
               }
        ) {
        }
   }
   
// the other option is to use pointerInteropFilter 
// the problem with this is that when used with the horizontalPager it does not detect the ACTION_MOVE for horizontal scroll
 HorizontalPager(state = pagerState) { page ->
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(colors[page])
                .pointerInteropFilter { motionEvent ->
                    when (motionEvent.action) 
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                                // This is not detected for horizontal scroll
                            println("ACTION_MOVE")
                        }                    }
                    true
                }
        ) {
            Text("Hello")
        }
    }

If I can correctly detect a backward swipe then I should be able to set userScrollEnabled on the pager to disable the backward swipe.
Any other approach to disabling backward swiping would also work.

Have you thought about using the PagerState? It has the targetPage attribute which is the stop position related to a scroll motion.

I'm not sure how you would do this, I think it would also still allow you to do the gesture, then you would reset the targetPage, is this what you are suggesting? What I'm looking for is that one swipe destination is blocked, so the user just couldn't swipe to the previous card the swiping back gesture would be disabled

You can do it by gettin disabling user gesture via checking currentPageOffsetFraction or by using a gesture with PointerEventPass.Initial you can get gesture before horizontal scroll does as explained here. And by consuming event if pagerState.currentPageOffsetFraction is below zero you can prevent HorizontalPager getting it.

@Preview
@Composable
fun PagerScrollCancelBackwardScroll() {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {

        val pagerState = rememberPagerState {
            25
        }

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
            text = "Current page: ${pagerState.currentPage}\n" +
                    "settled Page: ${pagerState.settledPage}\n" +
                    "target Page: ${pagerState.targetPage}\n" +
                    "currentPageOffsetFraction: ${pagerState.currentPageOffsetFraction}\n" +
                    "isScrollInProgress: ${pagerState.isScrollInProgress}\n" +
                    "canScrollForward: ${pagerState.canScrollForward}\n" +
                    "canScrollBackward: ${pagerState.canScrollBackward}\n" +
                    "lastScrolledForward: ${pagerState.lastScrolledForward}\n" +
                    "lastScrolledBackward: ${pagerState.lastScrolledBackward}\n",
            fontSize = 18.sp
        )

        val scrollEnabled by remember {
            derivedStateOf {
                pagerState.currentPageOffsetFraction >= 0
            }
        }

        HorizontalPager(
            userScrollEnabled = scrollEnabled,
            state = pagerState,
            pageSpacing = 16.dp,
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .background(Color.LightGray, RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Page $it",
                    fontSize = 28.sp
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

Edit1: If you don't want to see overscroll effect
@Preview
@Composable
fun PagerScrollCancelBackwardScrollNoEffect() {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(16.dp)
    ) {

        val pagerState = rememberPagerState {
            5
        }

        HorizontalPager(
            modifier = Modifier
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    awaitEachGesture {

                        val currentPageOffsetFraction = pagerState.currentPageOffsetFraction

                        val isBackwardsScroll = currentPageOffsetFraction < 0
                        val down = awaitFirstDown(
                            pass = PointerEventPass.Initial
                        )
                        if (isBackwardsScroll) {
                            down.consume()
                        }

                        println("currentPageOffsetFraction: $currentPageOffsetFraction")

                        do {
                            val event: PointerEvent = awaitPointerEvent(
                                pass = PointerEventPass.Initial
                            )

                            event.changes.forEach {
                                val diffX = it.position.x - it.previousPosition.x

                                if (diffX > 0) {
                                    it.consume()
                                }
                            }

                        } while (event.changes.any { it.pressed })
                    }
                },
            state = pagerState,
            pageSpacing = 16.dp,
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(200.dp)
                    .background(Color.LightGray, RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Page $it",
                    fontSize = 28.sp
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

Edit2: If you have inner scrollable content
@Preview
@Composable
fun PagerScrollCancelBackwardNoScrollEffect() {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {


        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

        val pagerState = rememberPagerState {
            20
        }

        var userScrollEnabled by remember {
            mutableStateOf(true)
        }

        HorizontalPager(
            userScrollEnabled = userScrollEnabled,
            modifier = Modifier
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    awaitEachGesture {
                        awaitFirstDown(pass = PointerEventPass.Initial)

                        do {
                            val event: PointerEvent = awaitPointerEvent(
                                pass = PointerEventPass.Initial
                            )

                            event.changes.forEach {
                                val diffX = it.position.x - it.previousPosition.x

                                if (diffX > 0) {
                                    userScrollEnabled = false
                                } else {
                                    userScrollEnabled = true
                                }
                            }

                        } while (event.changes.any { it.pressed })
                    }
                },
            state = pagerState,
            pageSpacing = 16.dp,
        ) { page ->
            LazyColumn (
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
            ){
                items(30)
                {
                    Text(
                        text = "Page $page, item: $it",
                        fontSize = 28.sp
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Edit3 With NestedScrollConnection
You can also pass zero offset from parent to HorizontalPager with NestedScrollConnection if x is bigger than 0.
@Preview
@Composable
fun PagerScrollCancelBackwardScrollableContent() {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {

        val pagerState = rememberPagerState {
            20
        }


        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))

        val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

        val nestedScrollConnection = remember {
            object : NestedScrollConnection {
                override fun onPreScroll(available: Offset, source: NestedScrollSource): Offset {
                    println("onPreScroll available: $available")

                    val availableX = available.x

                    val consumed = if (availableX > 0) availableX else 0f
                    return Offset(consumed, 0f)
                }

                override fun onPostScroll(
                    consumed: Offset,
                    available: Offset,
                    source: NestedScrollSource
                ): Offset {

                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        pagerState.animateScrollToPage(pagerState.settledPage)
                    }
                    return super.onPostScroll(consumed, available, source)
                }
            }
        }

        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)) {
            HorizontalPager(
                state = pagerState,
                pageSpacing = 16.dp,
            ) { page ->
                LazyColumn(
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
                ) {
                    items(30)
                    {
                        Text(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .background(Color.Black)
                                .fillMaxWidth().padding(16.dp),
                            text = "Page $page, item: $it",
                            fontSize = 28.sp,
                            color = Color.White
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

In this one when you started scrolling you can't scroll back because it's always consumed. By modifying this you can change the amount it can scroll backwards not previous page as well.

I also explained going back to first page after scrolling last here with changing pass. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78629838/how-to-detect-an-attempt-to-swipe-past-the-bounds-of-a-horizontalpager/78630153#78630153

Video Showing Issue Thanks for your answer, it is partially working but it doesn't fully block swiping back, it seems to need the item to completely settle before disallowing swipe back. And once you can swipe back you can swipe through all previous items

Have you tried second one? Also with first one you can use it.position.x - it.previousPosition.x which gets value from current gesture instead of pagerState that gets fraction value from its gesture

I tried the second one, but it doesn't seem to disable the back swipe at all

@Fred updated second one, you can try that one again. As i mentioned in comments you can get position from gesture in scroll while down from pagerState. In emulator i had no issue. Let me check first one too for overscroll effect.

the second option works, but it completely mucks up my inner content which is a vertical scroll using a LazyColumn {, the vertical scroll inside the HorizontalPager worked before but if I now add your secondsolution i use the vertical scroll

You didn't mention about any scroll inner scroll in the question. It's expected for any scroll to be canceled as i mentioned in the link in the answer. Consuming event prevents other same gesture receiving it. Instead of consume you just need to replace with userScrollEnabled then.

@Fred check edit2 then which disables userScrollEnabled instead of consuming

Updated first example as well with derivedStateOf and userScrollEnabled with overlay effect

the second version using the userScrollEnabled is working fine with the vertical scroll, there is one minor issue in that you can still scroll backwards a small amount and see the previous item, screen recording showing this issue https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VMqNdLLIpc6gvtcoAanjLrYb9G9koloe/view?usp=sharing. Thanks for your suggested solutions on this, appreciated

It's interesting even before getting gesture before Pager you say you experience this issue. There is also the one with derivedStateOf i posted

Hi, both of your answers the dervicedState and setting userScrollEnabled work, there is a tiny but of drag back which I can live with, thanks for your help, I'll mark this as answered, cheers

For anyone who doesn't have inner scrollable composables consuming gestures doesn't require recomposition so it won't have this scrolling issue i guess.
