# Android Jetpack Compose width / height / size modifier vs requiredWidth / requiredHeight / requiredSize

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Android Jetpack Compose contains [`width()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#width), [`height()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#height) and [`size()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#size) layout modifiers as well as [`requiredWidth()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#requiredwidth), [`requiredHeight()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#requiredheight) and [`requiredSize()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#requiredsize). What is the difference between these two sets of modifiers? Should I use *plain* modifiers or *required* ones?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The difference is that *plain* modifiers like [width()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#width) take into account layout [Constraints](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/unit/Constraints.html) while *required* modifiers like [requiredWidth()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#requiredwidth) ignore them. You can think of constrains as min/max width/height of a measured element. To better understand how layout modifiers and constraints work take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65698101/4858777).

Let's see an example of *width* modifier, *height* and *size* behave the same way.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun WidthModifierExample() {
    val columnWidth = 200.dp

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(columnWidth)
            .border(1.dp, Color.Gray)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "requiredWidth = parent - 50",
            modifier = Modifier
                .requiredWidth(columnWidth - 50.dp)
                .background(Color.LightGray)
        )
        Text(
            text = "requiredWidth = parent + 50",
            modifier = Modifier
                .requiredWidth(columnWidth + 50.dp)
                .background(Color.LightGray)
        )
        Text(
            text = "width = parent - 50",
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(columnWidth - 50.dp)
                .background(Color.LightGray),
        )
        Text(
            text = "width = parent + 50",
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(columnWidth + 50.dp)
                .background(Color.LightGray)
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

The dark gray border is the column boundaries, the texts background is light gray. `Modifier.width(200.dp)` is applied to the column so it receives `minWidth = 200dp; maxWidth = 200dp` constraints. The [Column](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#column) layout doesn't limit its children minimum width so each child gets `minWidth = 0; maxWidth = 200dp` constraints. The first two texts use `requiredWidth()` modifier which ignores this constraints so the second text is wider than the parent column. The last text width is reduced to `200dp` according to the `maxWidth = 200dp` constraint because it uses `width()` modifier instead.

In the example above only the maximum width of the texts was constrained. Lets see another example where the minimum width is constrained as well:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun WidthModifierExample() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.border(1.dp, Color.Gray)
    ) {
        val minWidth = 140
        val maxWidth = 200
        val widthDescriptions = arrayOf(
            WidthDescription(minWidth - 50, "min - 50"),
            WidthDescription((minWidth + maxWidth) / 2, "between min and max"),
            WidthDescription(maxWidth + 50, "max + 50")
        )

        for (widthDescription in widthDescriptions) {
            Text(
                text = "requiredWidth = ${widthDescription.description}",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .border(.5.dp, Color.Red)
                    .widthIn(minWidth.dp, maxWidth.dp)
                    .background(Color.LightGray)
                    .requiredWidth(widthDescription.width.dp)
            )
        }

        for (widthDescription in widthDescriptions) {
            Text(
                text = "width = ${widthDescription.description}",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .border(.5.dp, Color.Red)
                    .widthIn(minWidth.dp, maxWidth.dp)
                    .background(Color.LightGray)
                    .width(widthDescription.width.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}

data class WidthDescription(
    val width: Int,
    val description: String
)
```

[image]

In this case the `Column()` doesn't add any constraints but each child `Text()` is wrapped in [widthIn()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#widthin) modifier which adds its own constrains. The light gray background shows the texts size while the red border shows dimensions of the resulting element. As you can see `requiredWidth()` modifier of the first three texts ignores the outer constrains, as the result the element width and its child `Text()` width might be different. The last three texts uses `width()` modifier which takes into account the constrains so `Text()` width is always matches the resulting element.

Answer (score 25):

In jetpack Compose dimensions of Composable or child Composables are set using Constraints which is a set of dimensions and flags for being bounded or finite. `Modifier.requiredX` are used for widening Constraints or forcing new Constraints but can easily break your layout if the constraints are not in limit of parent's.

```
/**
 * Create a [Constraints]. [minWidth] and [minHeight] must be positive and
 * [maxWidth] and [maxHeight] must be greater than or equal to [minWidth] and [minHeight],
 * respectively, or [Infinity][Constraints.Infinity].
 */
@Stable
fun Constraints(
    minWidth: Int = 0,
    maxWidth: Int = Constraints.Infinity,
    minHeight: Int = 0,
    maxHeight: Int = Constraints.Infinity
): Constraints {
    require(maxWidth >= minWidth) {
        "maxWidth($maxWidth) must be >= than minWidth($minWidth)"
    }
    require(maxHeight >= minHeight) {
        "maxHeight($maxHeight) must be >= than minHeight($minHeight)"
    }
    require(minWidth >= 0 && minHeight >= 0) {
        "minWidth($minWidth) and minHeight($minHeight) must be >= 0"
    }
    return Constraints.createConstraints(minWidth, maxWidth, minHeight, maxHeight)
}
```

based on `Constraints` during measurement width and height are assigned to Composables as `Placeable`s. Size modifiers do inside measure function that returns `MeasureResult`.

```
    val placeable = measurable.measure(wrappedConstraints)
    return layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
        placeable.placeRelative(0, 0)
    }
```

When we assign any size Modifier we actually do not assign a size we pass a `Constraints` and based on the range of min-max properties of `Constraints` Composable is measured inside `MeasureScope` and placed inside `PlacementScope` or `layout()` function.

For instance, on a device with density 1.0 Modifier.size(50.dp) passes `Constraints(minWidth = 50, maxWidth = 50, minHeight = 50, maxHewight= 50)`. We set a fixed range of `Constraints` to measure our Composable which only can have 50.dp size.

If we set one with range `Modifier.sizeIn` for instance `Modifier.sizeIn(minWidth=50, maxWidth=100, minHeight=50, maxHeight=100)` Composable can be between 50.dp and 100.dp because we assign a Constraints with open range.

When we assign `Modifier.size(50.dp).size(100.dp)` we pass
`Constraint(50, 50, 50, 50)` to second size modifier which has target Constraints `Constraints(100, 100, 100, 100)`.

`Modifier.size/width/height/sizeIn/widthIn/heightIn` and `Modifier.requiredSize/SizeIn/width/WidthIn/HeightIn` modifiers share the same source code with a small difference, `size` modifiers check

```
/**
 * Takes [otherConstraints] and returns the result of coercing them in the current constraints.
 * Note this means that any size satisfying the resulting constraints will satisfy the current
 * constraints, but they might not satisfy the [otherConstraints] when the two set of constraints
 * are disjoint.
 * Examples (showing only width, height works the same):
 * (minWidth=2, maxWidth=10).constrain(minWidth=7, maxWidth=12) -> (minWidth = 7, maxWidth = 10)
 * (minWidth=2, maxWidth=10).constrain(minWidth=11, maxWidth=12) -> (minWidth=10, maxWidth=10)
 * (minWidth=2, maxWidth=10).constrain(minWidth=5, maxWidth=7) -> (minWidth=5, maxWidth=7)
 */
fun Constraints.constrain(otherConstraints: Constraints) = Constraints(
    minWidth = otherConstraints.minWidth.coerceIn(minWidth, maxWidth),
    maxWidth = otherConstraints.maxWidth.coerceIn(minWidth, maxWidth),
    minHeight = otherConstraints.minHeight.coerceIn(minHeight, maxHeight),
    maxHeight = otherConstraints.maxHeight.coerceIn(minHeight, maxHeight)
)
```

On `Modifier.size/width/height/sizeIn/widthIn/heightIn` modifier assignment this check is done but for simplicity i will explain second size in chain for `Modifier.size(50.dp).size(100.dp)`

Constraints assigned with 100.dp is `otherConstraints` here, and min
and max comes from current size, in our case from `Modifier.size(50.dp)`, results `100.coerceIn(50, 50)` returns 50 that's why the first one is used.

```
If we chain Modifier.widthIn(50.dp, 100.dp).width(80.dp) it returns 80.dp

If we chain Modifier.widthIn(50.dp, 100.dp).width(120.dp) it returns 100.dp

If we chain Modifier.widthIn(50.dp, 100.dp).width(40.dp) returns 50.dp
```

[image]

```
@Composable
private fun ChainSizeModifiersSample() {
    TutorialText2(text = "❌fillMaxWidth().width(50.dp)")

    BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .width(50.dp)
            .border(2.dp, Color.Red)
    ) {
        Text(text = "minWidth: $minWidth, maxWidth: $maxWidth")
    }

    TutorialText2(text = "❌width(200).width(50.dp)")
    BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(200.dp)
            .width(50.dp)
            .border(2.dp, Color.Red)
    ) {
        Text(text = "minWidth: $minWidth, maxWidth: $maxWidth")
    }

    StyleableTutorialText(
        text = "2-) **Modifier.width/height/sizeIn** describes a range " +
                "between min and max values. It's allowed to narrow range but " +
                "not allowed to widen it as can be seen examples below."
    )

    TutorialText2(text = "✅widthIn(min = 100.dp, max = 200.dp).width(150.dp)")
    BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = Modifier
            .widthIn(min = 100.dp, max = 200.dp)
            .width(150.dp)
            .border(2.dp, Color.Green)
    ) {
        Text(text = "minWidth: $minWidth, maxWidth: $maxWidth")
    }

    TutorialText2(text = "❌widthIn(min = 100.dp, max = 200.dp).width(50.dp)")
    BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = Modifier
            .widthIn(min = 100.dp, max = 200.dp)
            .width(50.dp)
            .border(2.dp, Color.Red)
    ) {
        Text(text = "minWidth: $minWidth, maxWidth: $maxWidth")
    }

    TutorialText2(text = "❌widthIn(min = 100.dp, max = 200.dp).width(250.dp)")
    BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = Modifier
            .widthIn(min = 100.dp, max = 200.dp)
            .width(250.dp)
            .border(2.dp, Color.Red)
    ) {
        Text(text = "minWidth: $minWidth, maxWidth: $maxWidth")
    }
}
```

Even if `requiredX` modifiers share same code it has a minor difference where it returns `Constraints` with

```
        val resolvedMinWidth = if (minWidth != Dp.Unspecified) {
            targetConstraints.minWidth
        } else {
            constraints.minWidth.coerceAtMost(targetConstraints.maxWidth)
        }
        val resolvedMaxWidth = if (maxWidth != Dp.Unspecified) {
            targetConstraints.maxWidth
        } else {
            constraints.maxWidth.coerceAtLeast(targetConstraints.minWidth)
        }
        val resolvedMinHeight = if (minHeight != Dp.Unspecified) {
            targetConstraints.minHeight
        } else {
            constraints.minHeight.coerceAtMost(targetConstraints.maxHeight)
        }
        val resolvedMaxHeight = if (maxHeight != Dp.Unspecified) {
            targetConstraints.maxHeight
        } else {
            constraints.maxHeight.coerceAtLeast(targetConstraints.minHeight)
        }
```

If you pay attention to source code **size modifiers can only narrow** the range of Constraints but `requiredX` modifiers **can widen it too**, basically they have no limit like `size/width/height/sizeIn/widthIn/heightIn` where it can set any target Constraints after current one.

`Modifier.width(50.dp).requiredWidh(100.dp)` changes min and max of 50.dp to 100.dp where your Composable can be measured with min-max 100.dp so it gets assigned 100.dp width.

However if Constraints of parent or initial one is not abided, parent considers this as 50.dp, it tries to center content to center where it can push this child to left or right based on `requiredX` modifier being bigger or smaller than initial `size` modifier.

[image]

```
@Composable
private fun ChainRequiredSizeModifierSample() {
    // In these examples requiredWidth constraints do not match the one comes from Modifier.size
    // Because of that parent attempts to place them in center. When required is bigger
    // it's placed at (parent.max-max) at left side. When required is smaller content is
    // place at right side(centered in parent).
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(20.dp)
            .border(2.dp, Blue400)
    ) {
        TutorialText2(text = "❌size(100.dp).requiredWidth(140.dp)")
        BoxWithConstraints(
            modifier = Modifier
                .border(2.dp, Color.Red)
                .size(100.dp)
                .requiredWidth(140.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "minWidth: $minWidth, maxWidth: $maxWidth",
                modifier = Modifier.border(3.dp, Color.Green)
            )
        }

        TutorialText2(text = "❌size(100.dp).requiredWidth(80.dp)")
        BoxWithConstraints(
            modifier = Modifier
                .border(2.dp, Color.Red)
                .size(100.dp)
                .requiredWidth(80.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "minWidth: $minWidth, maxWidth: $maxWidth",
                modifier = Modifier.border(3.dp, Color.Green)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Code is available [here](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials/blob/master/Tutorial1-1Basics/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/tutorial1_1basics/chapter3_layout/Tutorial3_1_6ChainSizeModifiers.kt)

## When to use Modifier.requiredX

Generally `Modifier.requiredX` variants are used when you wish to force a minimum size but you can use it forcing max size too. CheckBox uses it force 20.dp size in

```
Canvas(modifier.wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center).requiredSize(CheckboxSize))
```

if you assign a size Modifier less than 20.dp you can see that it's not placed where it should be. Same goes for Slider too

```
   BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier
            .minimumInteractiveComponentSize()
            .requiredSizeIn(minWidth = ThumbRadius * 2, minHeight = ThumbRadius * 2)
```

They are **required** to have minimum size to display or draw properly. And if we assign a size that is not in required it tries to center as in exaples above.

[image]

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun RequiredSample() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(20.dp).border(2.dp, Color.Cyan)
    ) {
        Checkbox(checked = true, onCheckedChange = null, modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp))
        Spacer(Modifier.height(30.dp))
        Checkbox(checked = true, onCheckedChange = null, modifier = Modifier.size(10.dp))
        Spacer(Modifier.height(30.dp))
        Slider(
            value = 0f,
            onValueChange = {},
            modifier = Modifier.size(48.dp).border(2.dp, Color.Green)
        )
        Spacer(Modifier.height(30.dp))
        Slider(
            value = 0f,
            onValueChange = {},
            modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp).border(2.dp, Color.Green)
        )
    }
}
```

## Size Modifiers

### Modifier.width/height()

Returns fixed Constraints or one with equal minWidth/Height and maxWidth/Height.
So Child Composables are limited to this Constraints

### Modifier.fillmaxWidth/Height(fraction)

Covers fraction of space that is available from parent's max constraints. It returns parent width/height as min and max width/height of

### Modifier.width/heightIn(min)

Reserves minimum width/height as this value so child Composables can be measured using this dimension. Children can be lower than this value or greater until max width/height

### Modifier.width/heightIn(max)

This is the max width/height children can be measured with. Children Composables cannot be measured with dimension bigger than max width/height.

[image]

```
@Composable
private fun ConstraintsSample1() {
    Text(text = "Fixed Size")
    BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier
        .size(100.dp)
        .border(3.dp, Color.Green)) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp)
            .background(Color.Red))
    }

    Spacer(modifier=Modifier.height(10.dp))
    BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier
        .size(100.dp)
        .border(3.dp, Color.Green)) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(150.dp)
            .background(Color.Red))
    }

    Text(text = "widthIn(min)")

    BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier
        .widthIn(min = 100.dp)
        .border(3.dp, Color.Green)) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp)
            .background(Color.Red))
    }

    Spacer(modifier=Modifier.height(10.dp))
    BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier
        .widthIn(min = 100.dp)
        .border(3.dp, Color.Green)) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(150.dp)
            .background(Color.Red))
    }


    Text(text = "widthIn(max)")

    BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier
        .widthIn(max = 100.dp)
        .border(3.dp, Color.Green)) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp)
            .background(Color.Red))
    }

    Spacer(modifier=Modifier.height(10.dp))
    BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier
        .widthIn(max = 100.dp)
        .border(3.dp, Color.Green)) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(150.dp)
            .background(Color.Red))
    }
}
```

### Modifier.requiredWidth/Height()

Constrain the width/height of the content to be between `minDp` and `maxDp`. If the content chooses a size that does not satisfy the incoming Constraints, the parent layout will be reported a size coerced in the Constraints, and the position of the content will be automatically offset to be centered on the space assigned to the child by the parent layout under the assumption that Constraints were respected.

For instance when you set `Modifier.size(50.dp).size(100.dp)` first size modifier is applied however if you user requiredIn

```
Modifier.size(50.dp).requiredSize(100.dp)
```

100.dp is but layout is placed as half of difference between 2 dimensions

[image]

```
@Composable
private fun ConstraintsSample2() {

    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(30.dp)
        .border(4.dp, Color.Cyan)) {

        Text(text = "Chaining size modifiers")

        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp)
            .background(Color.Yellow))

        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp)
            .size(100.dp)
            .background(Color.Red))

        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp)
            .requiredSizeIn(100.dp)
            .background(Color.Green))


        Text(text = "widthIn(max)")

        BoxWithConstraints(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(100.dp)
                .border(3.dp, Color.Green)
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .requiredWidthIn(min = 20.dp, max = 50.dp)
                    .height(50.dp)
                    .background(Color.Red)
            )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        BoxWithConstraints(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(100.dp)
                .border(3.dp, Color.Green)
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .requiredWidthIn(min = 150.dp, max = 200.dp)
                    .height(50.dp)
                    .background(Color.Red)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

In the sample below when TextField doesn't have parent with fixed size it grows till max width. If fixed size that is smaller than TextField is set when Modifier.widthIn() is used TextField is set to parent width while Modifier.requiredWidthIn() jumps out of parent as (TextField size - parent size)/2

[image]

```
@Composable
private fun TextFieldSamples() {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(20.dp).border(2.dp, Color.Cyan)
    ) {

        var text1 by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

        Column(modifier = Modifier) {
            TextField(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .border(2.dp, Color.Green)
                    .widthIn(56.dp),
                value = text1,
                onValueChange = { text1 = it }
            )

            TextField(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .border(2.dp, Color.Red)
                    .requiredWidth(56.dp),
                value = text1, onValueChange = { text1 = it })
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))

        var text2 by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

        Column(modifier = Modifier.width(50.dp)) {
            TextField(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .border(2.dp, Color.Green)
                    .widthIn(56.dp),
                value = text2, onValueChange = { text2 = it })

            TextField(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .border(2.dp, Color.Red)
                    .requiredWidth(56.dp),
                value = text2, onValueChange = { text2 = it })
        }
    }
}
```

## Constraints

Constraints change based on size modifiers, vertical/horizontal scroll or how parent chooses to limit or want to use min or max dimension.

Max device on my device width is 1080px, and 200.dp is 525px in the samples below. And used verticalScroll that's why height is measured with `Constraints.Infinity`

[image]

```
@Composable
fun ConstraintsSample3() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier) {

        Text(text = "No Dimension Modifier")

        BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier.background(Brown400)) {
            val hasBoundedWidth = constraints.hasBoundedWidth
            val hasFixedWidth = constraints.hasFixedWidth
            val minWidth = constraints.minWidth
            val maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth

            val hasBoundedHeight = constraints.hasBoundedHeight
            val hasFixedHeight = constraints.hasFixedHeight
            val minHeight = constraints.minHeight
            val maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight
            Text(
                "minWidth: $minWidth, maxWidth: $maxWidth\n" +
                        "hasBoundedWidth: $hasBoundedWidth, hasFixedWidth: $hasFixedWidth\n" +
                        "minHeight: $minHeight, maxHeight: $maxHeight\n" +
                        "hasBoundedHeight: $hasBoundedHeight, hasFixedHeight: $hasFixedHeight",
                color = Color.White
            )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Text(text = "FillMaxWidth and 200.dp Height")
        BoxWithConstraints(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(200.dp)
                .background(Red400)
        ) {
            val hasBoundedWidth = constraints.hasBoundedWidth
            val hasFixedWidth = constraints.hasFixedWidth
            val minWidth = constraints.minWidth
            val maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth

            val hasBoundedHeight = constraints.hasBoundedHeight
            val hasFixedHeight = constraints.hasFixedHeight
            val minHeight = constraints.minHeight
            val maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight
            Text(
                "minWidth: $minWidth, maxWidth: $maxWidth\n" +
                        "hasBoundedWidth: $hasBoundedWidth, hasFixedWidth: $hasFixedWidth\n" +
                        "minHeight: $minHeight, maxHeight: $maxHeight\n" +
                        "hasBoundedHeight: $hasBoundedHeight, hasFixedHeight: $hasFixedHeight",
                color = Color.White
            )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Text(text = "wrapContentSize()")
        BoxWithConstraints(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentSize()
                .background(Orange400)
        ) {

            val hasBoundedWidth = constraints.hasBoundedWidth
            val hasFixedWidth = constraints.hasFixedWidth
            val minWidth = constraints.minWidth
            val maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth

            val hasBoundedHeight = constraints.hasBoundedHeight
            val hasFixedHeight = constraints.hasFixedHeight
            val minHeight = constraints.minHeight
            val maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight
            Text(
                "minWidth: $minWidth, maxWidth: $maxWidth\n" +
                        "hasBoundedWidth: $hasBoundedWidth\n" +
                        "hasFixedWidth: $hasFixedWidth\n" +
                        "minHeight: $minHeight\n" +
                        "maxHeight: $maxHeight\n" +
                        "hasBoundedHeight: $hasBoundedHeight\n" +
                        "hasFixedHeight: $hasFixedHeight",
                color = Color.White
            )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Text(text = "200.dp Width and Height")
        BoxWithConstraints(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(200.dp)
                .height(200.dp)
                .background(Green400)
        ) {

            val hasBoundedWidth = constraints.hasBoundedWidth
            val hasFixedWidth = constraints.hasFixedWidth
            val minWidth = constraints.minWidth
            val maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth

            val hasBoundedHeight = constraints.hasBoundedHeight
            val hasFixedHeight = constraints.hasFixedHeight
            val minHeight = constraints.minHeight
            val maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight
            Text(
                "minWidth: $minWidth, maxWidth: $maxWidth\n" +
                        "hasBoundedWidth: $hasBoundedWidth, hasFixedWidth: $hasFixedWidth\n" +
                        "minHeight: $minHeight, maxHeight: $maxHeight\n" +
                        "hasBoundedHeight: $hasBoundedHeight, hasFixedHeight: $hasFixedHeight",
                color = Color.White
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

```
@Composable
private fun BoxWithConstraintsSample4() {
    Text(text = "200.dp WidthIn(min) and HeightIn(min)")
    BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = Modifier
            .widthIn(min = 200.dp)
            .heightIn(200.dp)
            .background(Blue400)
    ) {

        val hasBoundedWidth = constraints.hasBoundedWidth
        val hasFixedWidth = constraints.hasFixedWidth
        val minWidth = constraints.minWidth
        val maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth

        val hasBoundedHeight = constraints.hasBoundedHeight
        val hasFixedHeight = constraints.hasFixedHeight
        val minHeight = constraints.minHeight
        val maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight
        Text(
            "minWidth: $minWidth, maxWidth: $maxWidth\n" +
                    "hasBoundedWidth: $hasBoundedWidth, hasFixedWidth: $hasFixedWidth\n" +
                    "minHeight: $minHeight, maxHeight: $maxHeight\n" +
                    "hasBoundedHeight: $hasBoundedHeight, hasFixedHeight: $hasFixedHeight",
            color = Color.White
        )
    }

    Text(text = "200.dp requiredWidth(min) and requiredHeight(min)")
    BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = Modifier
            .requiredWidthIn(min = 200.dp)
            .requiredHeightIn(200.dp)
            .background(Pink400)
    ) {

        val hasBoundedWidth = constraints.hasBoundedWidth
        val hasFixedWidth = constraints.hasFixedWidth
        val minWidth = constraints.minWidth
        val maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth

        val hasBoundedHeight = constraints.hasBoundedHeight
        val hasFixedHeight = constraints.hasFixedHeight
        val minHeight = constraints.minHeight
        val maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight
        Text(
            "minWidth: $minWidth, maxWidth: $maxWidth\n" +
                    "hasBoundedWidth: $hasBoundedWidth, hasFixedWidth: $hasFixedWidth\n" +
                    "minHeight: $minHeight, maxHeight: $maxHeight\n" +
                    "hasBoundedHeight: $hasBoundedHeight, hasFixedHeight: $hasFixedHeight",
            color = Color.White
        )
    }

    Text(text = "200.dp defaultMinSize()")
    BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = Modifier
            .defaultMinSize(200.dp)
            .background(Pink400)
    ) {

        val hasBoundedWidth = constraints.hasBoundedWidth
        val hasFixedWidth = constraints.hasFixedWidth
        val minWidth = constraints.minWidth
        val maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth

        val hasBoundedHeight = constraints.hasBoundedHeight
        val hasFixedHeight = constraints.hasFixedHeight
        val minHeight = constraints.minHeight
        val maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight
        Text(
            "minWidth: $minWidth, maxWidth: $maxWidth\n" +
                    "hasBoundedWidth: $hasBoundedWidth, hasFixedWidth: $hasFixedWidth\n" +
                    "minHeight: $minHeight, maxHeight: $maxHeight\n" +
                    "hasBoundedHeight: $hasBoundedHeight, hasFixedHeight: $hasFixedHeight",
            color = Color.White
        )
    }

    Text(text = "200.dp WidthIn(max)")
    BoxWithConstraints(
        modifier = Modifier
            .widthIn(max = 200.dp)
            .background(Purple400)
    ) {

        val hasBoundedWidth = constraints.hasBoundedWidth
        val hasFixedWidth = constraints.hasFixedWidth
        val minWidth = constraints.minWidth
        val maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth

        val hasBoundedHeight = constraints.hasBoundedHeight
        val hasFixedHeight = constraints.hasFixedHeight
        val minHeight = constraints.minHeight
        val maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight
        Text(
            "minWidth: $minWidth, maxWidth: $maxWidth\n" +
                    "hasBoundedWidth: $hasBoundedWidth, hasFixedWidth: $hasFixedWidth\n" +
                    "minHeight: $minHeight, maxHeight: $maxHeight\n" +
                    "hasBoundedHeight: $hasBoundedHeight, hasFixedHeight: $hasFixedHeight",
            color = Color.White
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Placeables` ?

Comment: Placeable is what you get from `measureable.measure(constraints)`. You can position a Compoasble using `placeable.place/placeRelative/placeWithLayer` inside parent. Check this [answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70904979/how-align-to-bottom-a-row-in-jetpack-compose/70905004#70905004) custom layout part. And there are many custom layout samples in this [tutorial](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials#3-2-1-custom-layout) with different constraints. To create a custom layout you measure using constraints get placeable then place it according to requirements

Comment: Perfect thanks for great explain. I am learning all of these because of this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74701726/11560810). Do you have any idea, how to solve this?

Comment: @vivekmodi i explained here how to use layout, constraints, measurable, placeable and layoutId. It might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74730550/how-to-use-xmls-androidid-in-jetpack-compose/74731534#74731534 I will create a mega answer about how to use these and create custom layouts

Comment: One more question related to compose, which coverage tool are you using ?