# Full screen dialog in Android Compose does not take full screen height

Tags: android, dialog, android-jetpack-compose

```
Dialog(
  properties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false),
  onDismissRequest = {viewModel.showDialog.value = false}
){
  Column(modifier = Modifier.width(LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.dp)
    .height(LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp.dp).background(color = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 1f))) {

  }
}
```

Running this code results in a dialog with fullscreen, but the height does not fully match the screen height.

Is there any way to make the dialog take full width and height of the screen size?

Please find the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: How were you able to remove the system navigation buttons when the modal comes up? I have this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74465492/jetpack-compose-immersive-mode-dialog?noredirect=1#comment131465024_74465492

Answer (score 6):

If you take a took at how [screenHeightDp](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration#screenHeightDp) is defined.

> The current height of the available screen space, in dp units, corresponding to screen height resource qualifier.

Apparently, It excludes the area occupied by window insets, such as the status bar, navigation bar, and cutouts.

So here is a solution I managed to solve the problem. It try to get entire screen size from WindowManager. and feed them via `Modifier.requiredSize()`. Note that it is important to ignore parent constraints by using `requiredSize`, otherwise it won't work. More info at https://stackoverflow.com/a/65779227/157675 .

```
    Dialog(
        properties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false),
        onDismissRequest = onDismiss
    ) {
        val context = LocalContext.current
        val windowManager =
            remember { context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager }

        val metrics = DisplayMetrics().apply {
            windowManager.defaultDisplay.getRealMetrics(this)
        }
        val (width, height) = with(LocalDensity.current) {
            Pair(metrics.widthPixels.toDp(), metrics.heightPixels.toDp())
        }
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .requiredSize(width, height)
                .background(color = Color.Green)
        ) {
           // ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: this works for height, but width is not completely full with this approach.

Comment: @mrzbn For that you must set https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/window/DialogProperties#usePlatformDefaultWidth() to false

Answer (score -1):

For making the dialog fill the full screen either use `Modifier.fillMaxSize()` or use `Modifier.fillMaxWidth()` along with `Modifier.fillMaxHeight()`.

Comment: Tried that, does't help :(