# Jetpack Compose Immersive mode Dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have an Immersive application that's hiding the system bar using the Compose accompanist library in system navigation

```
val systemUiController: SystemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()

systemUiController.isStatusBarVisible = false // Status bar
systemUiController.isNavigationBarVisible = false // Navigation bar
systemUiController.isSystemBarsVisible = false // Status & Navigation bars
systemUiController.systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
```

This works fine but when I open a new alertDialog the system navigations show up again. Looking for a compose way of preventing the system bar to appear when `AlertDialog` or `DropdownMenu` is opened.

My code is basically a scaffold with a variable that controls showing/hiding the AlertDialog from the ViewModel.

Here is a gif to make it more clear. You can see the system navigation are hidden normally but when I clicked on `DropDownMenu` and when the `AlertDialog` they appear.
[image]

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73089753/5513788

Comment: Different issues. I actually don't want a full-screen modal. I just want to keep the system navigation hidden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Want to answer my own question in case anyone else is looking for a solution. Please follow the [Github conversation](https://github.com/google/accompanist/issues/1415)