# How align to bottom a row in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-layout

I have a Column with some rows, and I want to align the last row at the botton, but this row is never located at the bottom of the screen, it stays right after the previous row:

```
    Column {
        // RED BOX
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(130.dp)                
                .padding(vertical = 15.dp, horizontal = 30.dp),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Column {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(id = R.string.app_name),
                    style = TextStyle(fontSize = 40.sp),
                    color = Color.White
                )
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(id = R.string.app_description),
                    style = TextStyle(fontSize = 13.sp),
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    color = Color.Black
                )
            }
        }

        Spacer(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(15.dp)
        )

        // GREEN BOX
        val currentRoute = currentRoute(navController)
        items.forEach { item ->
            DrawerItem(item = item, selected = currentRoute == item.route) {
                navController.navigate(item.route) {
                    launchSingleTop = true
                }

                scope.launch {
                    scaffoldState.drawerState.close()
                }
            }
        }

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(vertical = 15.dp, horizontal = 30.dp),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            Text(
                text = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME,
                style = TextStyle(fontSize = 11.sp),
                color = Color.Black,
            )
        }
    }
```

I want to get the same as I show in the picture. I want to have the first row (red), then the second row (green) and then a third row that fits at the bottom of the screen (blue)

[image]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can do it in many ways.

You can use a Column with `verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween` assigning a `weight(1f,false)` to the last row:

```
  Column(
     Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
     verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween) {
     
     //All elements 
     Column {

        // RED BOX
        
        //...
        Spacer(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Green)
                .height(15.dp)
        )

       //... Green box
    }

    //LAST ROW
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .weight(1f, false)
    ) {
        //...
    }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: It is not working if my inside column has `verticalScroll()` Is there any way to achieve similar scenario in scrollable content.

Answer (score 43):

You can use a `Spacer(modifier.weight(1f))` between GreenBox and Blue Box to create space between them or you can create your custom column with `Layout` function and  set y position of last `Placeable` as height of `Composable`  - height of last `Composble`

```
    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .background(Color.LightGray)) {
        Text(
            "First Text",
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color(0xffF44336)),
            color = Color.White
        )
        Text(
            "Second Text",
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color(0xff9C27B0)),
            color = Color.White
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
        Text(
            "Third Text",
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color(0xff2196F3)),
            color = Color.White
        )
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Custom Layout

```
@Composable
private fun CustomColumn(
    modifier: Modifier,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Layout(
        modifier = modifier,
        content = content
    ) { measurables, constraints ->

        val looseConstraints = constraints.copy(
            minWidth = 0,
            maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth,
            minHeight = 0,
            maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight
        )

        // Don't constrain child views further, measure them with given constraints
        // List of measured children
        val placeables = measurables.map { measurable ->
            // Measure each child
            measurable.measure(looseConstraints)
        }

        // Track the y co-ord we have placed children up to
        var yPosition = 0


        // Set the size of the layout as big as it can
        layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {
            // Place children in the parent layout
            placeables.forEachIndexed { index, placeable ->

                println("Placeable width: ${placeable.width}, measuredWidth: ${placeable.measuredWidth}")
                // Position item on the screen
                if (index == placeables.size - 1) {
                    placeable.placeRelative(x = 0, y = constraints.maxHeight - placeable.height)
                } else {
                    placeable.placeRelative(x = 0, y = yPosition)
                }

                // Record the y co-ord placed up to
                yPosition += placeable.height
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
    CustomColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .background(Color.LightGray)
    ) {
        Text(
            "First Text",
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color(0xffF44336)),
            color = Color.White
        )
        Text(
            "Second Text",
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color(0xff9C27B0)),
            color = Color.White
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
        Text(
            "Third Text",
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color(0xff2196F3)),
            color = Color.White
        )
    }
```

Result:
[image]

In this example with Layout you should consider how you measure your measureables with Constraints and your total width and height. It requires a little bit practice but you get more unique designs and with less work(more optimised) composables than ready ones. Here i set layout as maxWidth so no matter which width you assign it takes whole width. It's for demonstration you can set max width or height in `layout` based on your needs.

Comment: setting a specific height of a view seems like a really bad idea.

Comment: It's for demonstration. Having a fixed height is not the main point in the examples above. Examples above are about placing last Composable at the bottom of parent Composable using a`Spacer` with `Modifier.weight` or creating a custom Composable with `Layout` and placing `placeables`

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me:

The structure is something like this:

```
Column // arrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
  Column
    Row 1
    Row 2
    Row 3
  Row 4
```

```
@Preview(showSystemUi = true)
@Composable
fun AlignBottomExample() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {

        Column() {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.height(100.dp)
                    .background(Color.Magenta)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
            ) {
                Text(text = "Row 1")
            }
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.height(100.dp)
                    .background(Color.Cyan)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
            ) {
                Text(text = "Row 2")
            }
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.height(100.dp)
                    .background(Color.Yellow)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
            ) {
                Text(text = "Row 3")
            }
        }

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.height(100.dp)
                .background(Color.Green)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
        ) {
            Text(text = "Row 4")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesnt work when elements exceed the screen size because the green row will disappear for example.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is using Scaffold:

```
Scaffold(
    topBar = { /* you can add top bar content  */ },
    bottomBar = {
        Text("Bottom bar",
            fontSize = 50.sp,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.Black),
        )
    }
) {
    Text(
        "Main content.",
        fontSize = 50.sp,
        color = Color.White,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .background(Color.Gray),

    )
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I have to login to vote for you ! Nice bro

Comment: I am flattered <3

Answer (score 0):

This approach works for me and also solve if middle content doesn't fit in screen

```
@Composable
fun FixedTopBottomScrollableMiddleLayout() {
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    // Top Element
    Text(
        text = "Top Element",
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
    )

    // Middle Element (Scrollable)
    Box(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
        Text(
            text = "This is a long text that will scroll. It demonstrates how to make the middle element scrollable while keeping the top and bottom elements fixed.",
            modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        )
    }

    // Bottom Element
    Text(
        text = "Bottom Element",
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
    )
}
}
```