# Modifier weight not available in jetpack compose 1.1.1

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am using compose 1.1.1 in my jetpack compose. I cannot update to latest version. I am want something like this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70905133/11560810). I am getting error on my `weight` modifier. Can someone guide me how can I get my `weight` modifier in `Row`?

```
implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test:$compose_version"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.activity:activity-compose:$compose_version"
```

**Row.kt**

```
Column {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f, false)
    ) {
        //...
    }
 }
```

[image]

**Error**

```
Expression 'weight' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found
```

Many Thanks

**UPDATE**

I am adding my whole code here please have a look...

```
@Composable
fun Input(optionData: OptionData) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Item(optionData)
    }
}


@Composable
fun Item(optionData: OptionData) {
    /// more item of compose i.e. Text, Textfield
    Submit()
}

@Composable
fun Submit() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f, false)
    ) {
        //...
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

After trying @Thracian solution it solve the problem of `weight` but my view is not going to bottom.

```
@Composable
fun Submit() {
    Column {
        OnSubmit {
            PrimaryMaterialButton(text = stringResource(id = R.string.submit)) {

            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ColumnScope.OnSubmit(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f, false)
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```

Comment: `weight` is a modifier you put on a child of a `Row` or `Column`. Is the `Row` you are putting that modifier on in a `Row` or `Column` itself?

Comment: @ianhanniballake first is `Column` and the `Row`.

Comment: I updated my question as well to clear that.

Comment: @vivekmodi That error is returned when you are trying to use `Modifier.weight` on a composable that does not have a `Row` or `Column` as a parent. Please show us more of the code structure around that `Row`. If this is inside a composable function that is called inside a `Column` then you have to use the `ColumnScope` as the receiver of the composable function for that to work.

Comment: @Ma3x I added my whole structure. Please have a look into this and guide me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@Composable
fun Submit() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f, false)
    ) {
        //...
    }
}
```

For this code to be able to access Modifier.weight() from `Column` it should have receiver as `ColumnScope`. Some modifiers are created with scope so they are available only inside that scope such as Modifier.weight for Row or Column or Modifier.matchParentSize for Box.

```
@Composable
fun ColumnScope.Submit() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f, false)
    ) {
        //...
    }
}


// Allowed
Column {
    Submit()
}

//Not Allowed
Row() {
    Submit()
}
```

Comment: one problem I am putting my view bottom of screen but it doesn't work..

Comment: How does it not work exactly?

Comment: can you please check `UPDATE 2` section in my question.

Comment: If your problem was aligning Submit button to bottom then you should add Spacer(modifier=Modifier.weight(1f)) and you don't need to add add weight for your Submit button

Comment: When Column or Row measures and places Composables it measures Composables that don't have weight modifiers then allocate space between Composables that have weight modifiers. If only one Composable has weight it occupies space that other Composables that don't occupy. And every child composable is placed same order they are declared with new measured heights

Comment: I think I understand that. It's better to open new question for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247114/discussion-between-thracian-and-vivek-modi).

Comment: can you help me on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73276689/11560810)