# How to create multicoloured box divided equally in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to show a horizontal box divided into multiple equals parts containing different colours. How can I use the specified integer to divide the box, then use the list of specified colours to colour the sections in?

**Expected result**

[image]

**Current reuslt**

[image]

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            NestedScrollingTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    MyScreen()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyReusableScaffold(scaffoldTitle: String, scaffoldFab: @Composable () -> Unit,
                       scaffoldContent: @Composable (contentPadding: PaddingValues) -> Unit) {
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.exitUntilCollapsedScrollBehavior()

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        topBar = {
            LargeTopAppBar(
                title = { Text(text = scaffoldTitle) },
                scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
            )
        },
        floatingActionButton = { scaffoldFab },
        content = { contentPadding -> scaffoldContent(contentPadding = contentPadding) }
    )
}

@Composable
fun ReusableRow(rowItems: Array<RowItems>) {
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

    Row(modifier = Modifier
        .height(300.dp)
        .horizontalScroll(state = scrollState),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            rowItems.forEach { rowItem ->
                MyInfoCard(cardTitle = rowItem.rowItemTitle, cardSubtitle = rowItem.rowItemDesc)
            }
    }
}

@Composable
fun <T> ReusableLazyColumn(
    header: @Composable () -> Unit,
    lazyColumnItems: Array<T>,
    lazyColumnItemLayout: @Composable Any.(item: T) -> Unit,
    onClickLazyColumnItem: (T) -> Unit
) {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        LazyColumn(
            state = listState,
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = 0.dp, bottom = 80.dp)
        ) {
            item { header.invoke() }
            item { Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(24.dp)) }
            items(lazyColumnItems) { itemC ->
                Row(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .clickable {
                        onClickLazyColumnItem(itemC)
                    }) {
                    lazyColumnItemLayout(itemC)
                }

                Divider(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface.copy(alpha = 0.2f))
            }
        }

        ButtonScrollToTopList(listState = listState)
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
    MyReusableScaffold(
        scaffoldTitle = "Demo",
        scaffoldFab = { /*TODO*/ },
        scaffoldContent = {
            MyScreenContent(contentPadding = it)
        }
    )
}

@Composable
fun MyScreenContent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues()
) {
    val rowItems = arrayOf(
        RowItems.ItemRowNeapolitan,
        RowItems.ItemRowSpumoni
    )

    val columnItems = arrayOf(
        ColumnItems.ItemPetitFour,
        ...
        ColumnItems.ItemUpsideDownCake
    )

    Box(modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(contentPadding)
    ) {
        Column(content = {
                ReusableLazyColumn(
                    header = { ReusableRow(rowItems) },
                    lazyColumnItems = columnItems,
                    lazyColumnItemLayout = {
                        Row { ... }
                    },

                    onClickLazyColumnItem = { listenerColumnItems }
                )
            }
        )
    }
}

enum class RowItems(val rowItemTitle: String, val rowItemDesc: String,
                    val barSectionCount: Int, val barSectionColors: List<Any>) {
    ItemRowNeapolitan("Neapolitan ice cream",
        "vanilla, chocolate, and strawberry",
        3, 
        listOf(0xFFFBFFFE, 0xFF774B3B, 0xFFEFAD89)
    ),
    ItemRowSpumoni("Spumoni ice cream",
        "vanilla, pistachio, and strawberry",
        3,
        listOf(0xFFFBFFFE, 0xFF93C572, 0xFFEFAD89)
    )
}

enum class ColumnItems(val columnItemTitle: String) {
    ItemPetitFour("Petit Four"),
    ...
    ItemUpsideDownCake("Upside Down Cake")
}

val listenerColumnItems: (ColumnItems) -> Unit = {...}

@Composable
fun MyInfoCard(
    cardTitle: String,
    cardSubtitle: String,
//    boxSections: Int,
//    boxSectionColours: Array<Any>
) {
    OutlinedCard(modifier = Modifier
        .height(350.dp)
        .padding(16.dp),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 16.dp),
    ) {
        Column() {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(???)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(30.dp)
            )
            Text(text = cardTitle)
            Text(text = cardSubtitle)
        }
    }
}

val listenerRowItems: (RowItems) -> Unit = { item ->
    when (item) {
        RowItems.ItemRowCheetah -> TODO()
        ...
        RowItems.ItemRowSonoma -> TODO()
    }
}

enum class ColumnItems(val columnItemTitle: String) {
    ItemPetitFour("Petit Four"),
    ...
    ItemUpsideDownCake("Upside Down Cake")
}


val listenerColumnItems: (ColumnItems) -> Unit = { item ->
    when (item) {
        ColumnItems.ItemPetitFour -> TODO()
        ...
        ColumnItems.ItemUpsideDownCake -> TODO()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Typing this on a phone, so some stuff *might* be wrong, will factcheck later <3)

a simple composable like:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Stackoverflow() {
    val listOfColors = listOf(Color.Gray, Color.Black, Color.Red)
    Row {
        listOfColors.forEach {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.height(50.dp).weight(1f).background(it))
        }
    }
}
```

should do the job (the `.weight(1f)` makes sure all of the boxes take the same amount of space)

Comment: Not suitable as it needs to be reusable

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done as as Modifier that draws multi-colored background

```
fun Modifier.multiColorBackground(
    colors: List<Color>
) = this.then(
    Modifier.drawBehind {
        if (colors.isNotEmpty()) {
            val colorCount = colors.size
            val width = size.width / colorCount
            colors.forEachIndexed { index, color ->
                drawRect(
                    color = color,
                    topLeft = Offset(index * width, 0f),
                    size = Size(width, size.height)
                )
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Result

[image]

Demo

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun ColorTest() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Black)
            .padding(top=20.dp)
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(60.dp)
                .multiColorBackground(listOf(Color.White, Brown400, Pink400))
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not appearing at all for some reason but yet if I put a `Text` box inside the Box it appears.

Comment: This Modifier.drawBehind relies on `size.width` which comes from size modifier applied to Composable or its content measurement. If you don't pass width and height size returns zero in `drawScope`. You can draw anywhere in `drawScope` unless clip is applied even if size is zero but when you need to use it there has to be some dimension applied to composable

Comment: PointerInputScope and DrawScope size comes from content or size modifiers. To be sure you can debug what size it returns when it doesn't appear

Comment: Very strange. So can something similar to `fillMaxWidth` be used to use the maxium width instead of a specific numerical value?

Comment: You can use any size modifier, i don't mean just Modifier.size, anything that changes min from 0 to another value. It's a Box without content lambda. Modifier.background() or Modifier.border also do not appear if Box doesn't have a size, `Box(modifier = Modifier.height(60.dp).background(Color.Red))`. This is not about Modifier, this is about not having Constraints with minWidth/Height bigger than 0. You can find which size modifier returns which constraints in Constraints section of this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73316247/5457853