# Jetpack compose Box not apply the CircleShape

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I met this question today.

```
@Preview(showBackground = true, backgroundColor = 0xffffff)
@Composable
fun PreviewBox() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(30.dp)
            .background(color = Color.Red)
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(60.dp)
            .background(color = Color.Green, shape = CircleShape))
    }
}
```

and the result is

[image: 1]

so i got an oval and i wonder why the CircleShape not work in this case.

I try search the docs but found nothing.

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: What i want is a green circle, not a green oval. I dont know why the CircleShape not work correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Modifier.height(30.dp) limits child Composable to 30.dp no matter how big height you give because it passes Constraints with maxHeight limited at pixel value of 30.dp.

You can either remove height(30.dp) in parent Box to let child Box be measured how big it wants but in this case red line also will be 60.dp big.

Also you can override this several ways. Under the hood both does the same thing increase Constraints maxWidth and maxHeight to 60.dp as with layout in last sample.

[image]

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewBox() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(color = Color.Red)
        ) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .size(60.dp)
                .background(color = Color.Green, shape = CircleShape))
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
        Text("wrapContentSize")
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(30.dp)
                .background(color = Color.Red)
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .wrapContentSize(unbounded = true)
                    .size(60.dp)
                    .background(color = Color.Green, shape = CircleShape)
            )
        }


        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
        Text("requiredSize")
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(30.dp)
                .background(color = Color.Red)
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .requiredSize(60.dp)
                    .background(color = Color.Green, shape = CircleShape)
            )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
        Text("layout")
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(30.dp)
                .background(color = Color.Red)
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .layout { measurable, constraints ->
                        val placeable = measurable.measure(
                            Constraints.fixed(
                                60.dp.roundToPx(),
                                60.dp.roundToPx()
                            )
                        )

                        layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                            placeable.placeRelative(0, 0)
                        }
                    }
                    .background(color = Color.Green, shape = CircleShape)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this valuable experience

Comment: If anyone interested i can explain why Modifier.size(30.dp).(60.dp) or passing a Constraints that do not match in child does not change child. I already have Modifier chain and size modifier samples here but i still can explain why it doesn't work either. https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials/blob/master/Tutorial1-1Basics/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/tutorial1_1basics/chapter3_layout/Tutorial3_1_6ChainSizeModifiers.kt

Comment: @thracianI will be very happy if you do this

Comment: Thanks!! I just realized that I have starred your project in github

Comment: @VahidGarousi updated this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73316247/5457853) but when i have time i will add one that covers other size modifiers, chaining, passing to child from parent and infinite constraints as well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve the shape of a circle, you must use the following modifier:
[image]

```kotlin
@Preview(showBackground = true, backgroundColor = 0xffffff)
@Composable
fun PreviewBox() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .requiredHeightIn(30.dp)
            .background(color = Color.Red)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(60.dp)
                .background(
                    color = Color.Green,
                    shape = CircleShape
                )
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want more information see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65779226/android-jetpack-compose-width-height-size-modifier-vs-requiredwidth-requir

Comment: There is no need to use requiredHeightIn(30.dp) here. You can use heightIn(30.dp) or even no height Modifier at all. Modifier.required is used to change limits of constraints that already limited. You simply put set minimum height Constraints which is generally 0 to pixel value of 30.dp, basically does nothing when child measures itself with 60.dp

Comment: So you just set the min height of the box to 30dp and it find the content is 60dp so it scale to 60dp. That is not what I want, i want to keep the red box' s height to 30dp. In my expection my green circle can cover the red area , I dont know why