# Animation with increasing sizes in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, jetpack-compose-animation

I want to make an animation of a button, when clicked, its sizes increase and go beyond the size of the Box(). I wrote an animation with a custom Shape, it works, but where it is used, you have to  write Modifier.size(21.dp) instead of Modifier.size(20.dp). And look like:

[1dp as a space for animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBoCK.png)

Can I somehow write an animation with an output beyond the sizes of Box()? Because now the solution looks a little complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default Composables like Box, Row or Column limit maximum height or width a child can get based on their maximum Constraints. You can find more details about Constraints and how size modifiers work under the hood in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65779226/android-jetpack-compose-width-height-size-modifier-vs-requiredwidth-requir/73316247#73316247).

What you should do is to force maximum `Constraints` beyond parent if you wish to increase a child's maximum dimensions bigger than parent.

You can use `Modifier.wrapContentSize(unBounded=true)`, `Modifier.requiredSize` or `Modifier.layout{}` which wrapContentSize also does under the hood to animate size beyond parents.

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun Test() {

    var target by remember {
        mutableStateOf(20.dp)
    }
    val size by animateDpAsState(target)

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(20.dp)
    ) {

        Button(
            onClick = {
                target = if (size == 20.dp) {
                    40.dp
                } else {
                    20.dp
                }
            }
        ) {
            Text("Current size $size")
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Box(modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp).border(1.dp, Color.Red)) {

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(size)
                    .background(Color.Blue)
            )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Box(modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp).border(1.dp, Color.Red)) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    // This will let child to get Constraints.Infinity for maxWidth and Height
                    // so it can be measured with next Size modifier's max bounds
                    .wrapContentSize(unbounded = true)
                    .size(size)
                    .background(Color.Green)
            )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Box(modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp).border(1.dp, Color.Red)) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    // This will let child to set max width and height as they choose
                    .requiredSize(size)
                    .background(Color.Magenta)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77059102/5457853 Another sample for increasing size beyond parent boundaries. Another option is to use `Layout` alongside with these 2 modifiers