# Composable: don't clip views

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Row, which contains "Spacer - Box - Spacer - Box - etc" inside.
All Boxes have same width and backgound with rounded corners.
But when there isn't enough space left, the last Box is clipped and due to it's rounded background it looks like its width differs from other boxes.

I've tried to use requiredWidth instead of width, but in this case the box overlaps other boxes and spacers (requiredWidth centers the box).
The only thing that helps, is adding horizontal scroll. But i don't need that view to be scrollable.
Is there any way to achieve the desired result?

Some pictures for better explanation.

This is how width/requiredWidth work:
[image]

This is how it maps to my real situation
[image]

Comment: I guess `LazyRow` should work for your requirement and you can disable horizontal scroll by: `userScrollEnabled = false` inside `LazyRow`

Comment: Good point, btw. But looks a bit hacky, doesn't it? Anyway, thnx. At least it matches my needs, will use it for now

Comment: Would you mind sharing how this works how it works with scroll? It's really interesting.

Comment: @Thracian added more info as an answer based on the advice above https://stackoverflow.com/a/77272569/6329995

Comment: @Lev161 the reason i asked how you do it with scroll was the reason it's not possible to do in your images because scroll increases maxWidth of Composable it's attached to to Constraints.Infinity, and you can do in your answer but it doesn't let content go beyond as in your images. To do that you need to measure last Composable as in my answer. And if you don't want to draw rest of the Composables that is out of Row bounds, third one, assign `Modifier.clipToBounds()`to Row

Comment: Basically you increase the min-max range that Row allows for the last item by assigning Modifier.wrapContent/requiredWidth/layout but with other 2 you can change where it's placed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default Composables or any Composable that is not assigned `Modifier.clipToBounds()`, `Modifier.clip` or `Modifier.graphicsLayer{clip}` do not clip content. You can draw anything outside a Composable using draw Modifiers for instance when no clip is set, it also applies changing position with Modifier.offset or Modifier.layout, etc.

What happens is Composables are measured with Constraints and Row and Column uses

```
var usedSpace = 0
for(measurable in measurable list) {measurable->
  measurable.measure(maxWith=constraints.maxWidth/Height - usedSpace)
  usedSpace += placeable.width/height
}
```

Because of that when there is no avilable space last child Composable might shrink down to 0.dp or 0 px.

When you assign `Modifier.requiredWidth()` you change maxWidth of Constraints to any value you assign but when layout width of parent Composable doesn't match its Constraints width it tries to center content. You can finde more detailed explanation about it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73316247/5457853).

If you don't want to center you can use `Modifier.wrapContentWidth(alignment=Start, unbounded=true)`

`unBounded` param increases Constraints maxWidth to `Constraints.Infinity` and content can be measured with their desired width and alignment sets its position instead of center.

You can also use `Modifier.layout` same way wrapContentWidth does, under the hood every size Modifier calls measurement and `layout()`.

[image]

I post 2 alternatives, you can comment out wrapContentWidth to see they both act same. And inside layout modifier you can inspect which Constraints.maxWith comes to next child and how and with what width they are set.

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun LayoutPlacingTest() {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(20.dp)
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .border(4.dp, Color.Gray)
                .width(300.dp)
                .background(Color.Yellow)
        ) {
            repeat(3) { index ->
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
//                        .wrapContentWidth(align = Alignment.Start, unbounded = true)
                        .layout { measurable, constraints ->
                            val placeable = measurable.measure(
                                constraints.copy(maxWidth = Constraints.Infinity)
                            )

                            println("placeable: ${placeable.width}, Constraints: $constraints")

                            layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                                val x = ((placeable.width - constraints.maxWidth) / 2).coerceAtLeast(0)
                                placeable.placeRelative(x, 0)
                            }
                        }
                        .size(100.dp)
                        .background(Color.Red, RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
                )
                if (index != 2) {
                    Spacer(Modifier.width(20.dp))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per request, adding some code including my final decision according to @Megh comment (formatting is a bit ruined to keep it short).

Here is my basic test Box:

```
    @Composable
    private fun BoxWithWidth() {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(125.dp)
                .height(28.dp)
                .clip(clip)
                .background(color)
        )
    }
```

Option 1: using Row *without scroll* and Boxes *with width*.
Result: last view has wrong width

```
    @Composable
    private fun ExampleRowWidth() {
        Row {
            BoxWithWidth()
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(25.dp))
            BoxWithWidth()
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(25.dp))
            BoxWithWidth()
        }
    }
```

[image]

Option 2: using Row *without scroll* and Boxes *with requiredWidth*.
Result: last view has correct width but wrong positioning

```
    @Composable
    private fun BoxWithRequiredWidth() {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .requiredWidth(125.dp)
                .height(28.dp)
                .clip(clip)
                .background(color)
        )
    }

    @Composable
    private fun ExampleRowRequiredWidth() {
        Row {
            BoxWithRequiredWidth()
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(25.dp))
            BoxWithRequiredWidth()
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(25.dp))
            BoxWithRequiredWidth()
        }
    }
```

[image]

Option 3: using Row *with scroll* and Boxes *with width*.
Result: works fine, but now it is scrollable (not what I need, as I'm using that in the skeleton)

```
    @Composable
    private fun ExampleRowScrollable() {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        ) {
            BoxWithWidth()
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(25.dp))
            BoxWithWidth()
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(25.dp))
            BoxWithWidth()
        }
    }
```

[image]

Option 4: using LazyRow (*disabled scroll*) and Boxes *with width*.
Result: that's what I need - correct width and positioning without scroll. Works fine and implemented easily, but still seems to be a bit hacky.

```
    @Composable
    private fun ExampleLazyRowNotScrollable() {
        LazyRow(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(25.dp),
            userScrollEnabled = false
        ) {
            item { BoxWithWidth() }
            item { BoxWithWidth() }
            item { BoxWithWidth() }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Option 5: using Row *without scroll* and Boxes *with requiredWidth and wrapContentWidth*
Result: and this seems to be a correct way to achieve the desired result. Works fine and no hacks at all.

```
    @Composable
    private fun BoxWithRequiredWidthAndAlignment() {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentWidth(align = Alignment.Start, unbounded = true)
                .requiredWidth(125.dp)
                .height(28.dp)
                .clip(clip)
                .background(color)
        )
    }

    @Composable
    private fun ExampleRowRequiredWidthAndAlignment() {
        Row {
            BoxWithRequiredWidthAndAlignment()
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(25.dp))
            BoxWithRequiredWidthAndAlignment()
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(25.dp))
            BoxWithRequiredWidthAndAlignment()
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: What i meant was how you accomplished this with scrollable Composable but in any case you want to measure a Composable full width and make it look like it's clipped, this is a good and practical answer.