# How is the modifier parameter of composables scoped in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

This is a somewhat theoretical question. Through what Kotlin language feature is the scoping of the modifier parameter of composables applied? Specifically, I'm referring to this chapter of the android developer documentation:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/modifiers#scope-safety

I understand how the compose content parameter is scoped through the *literal with receiver* mechanism, but I don't get how the scope is applied to the modifier parameter.

Just a pointer in the right direction would be sufficient (hopefully)

Thanks

Edit:
Question was based on a misunderstanding, sorry for the confusion. I'm adding some sample code to clarify (what I thought was happening):

```
    Row(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) { //I thought the weight function is available here, in the Row's modifier parameter because the parameter is passed into a Row composable
        Box(modifier = modifier.weight(1f)){} //weight function is actually only available here, in the Row's content, through the "literal with receiver" mechanism
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it only makes use of Kotlin Extension Functions. If you look at the samples provided at the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-functions), you will find the following example:

```
fun MutableList<Int>.swap(index1: Int, index2: Int) {
    val tmp = this[index1] // 'this' corresponds to the list
    //...
}
```

> The `this` keyword inside an extension function corresponds to the receiver object (the one that is passed before the dot).

From this sample we can see that from within the extension function of a class, we can **access** the class with `this` and can also access **the properties and functions of the class**.

When you look into the documentation of [`ColumnScope`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/ColumnScope), you will see that the Modifiers available in a `ColumnScope` simply are functions within that class. If you define your Composable as an extension function to that class, you can access its functions. If not, then the compiler cannot resolve it.

Also have a look at the short explanation provided [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/kotlin#scopes).

Answer (score 3):

To create a scoped Modifier first you need to create a scope.

```
interface CustomColumnScope {
    @Stable
    fun Modifier.horizontalAlign(align: HorizontalAlignment) = this.then(
        CustomColumnData(align)
    )

    companion object : CustomColumnScope
}
```

This is a custom scope for a custom `Layout` you wish to use this Modifier only within this scope.

CustomColumnData is the actual `Modifier`

```
private class CustomColumnData(
    val alignment: HorizontalAlignment
) : ParentDataModifier {

    override fun Density.modifyParentData(parentData: Any?) = this@CustomColumnData


    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {

        if (this === other) return true
        val otherModifier = other as? CustomColumnData ?: return false
        return alignment == otherModifier.alignment
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return alignment.hashCode()
    }

    override fun toString(): String =
        "CustomColumnData(alignment=$alignment)"
}
```

Since this is a alignment Modifier for a custom Composable it needs to have options to choose from.

```
enum class HorizontalAlignment {
    Start, Center, End
}
```

This is how you create custom scope and custom Modifier, how you do the implementation is inside Layout composable to set position of child Composables. Modifier.weight, align or matchParentSize works the same way.

This step is optional but makes it easier if you define Measurable extension properties. Measureables are what you use for getting from custom layout to get Placeables using Constraints. I have detailed answer about them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73316247/5457853).

```
private val Measurable.childData: CustomColumnData?
    get() = parentData as? CustomColumnData

private val Measurable.alignment: HorizontalAlignment
    get() = childData?.alignment ?: HorizontalAlignment.Start
```

This part requires basic knowledge of how to use `Layout`. You set your content, child composables as in Column, with Reciever of `CustomColumnScope`.

```
@Composable
fun CustomColumnWithScope(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable CustomColumnScope.() -> Unit
) {

    Layout(
        modifier = modifier,
        content = { CustomColumnScope.content() },
    ) { measurables: List<Measurable>, constraints: Constraints ->

        // We need to set minWidth to zero to wrap only placeable width
        val looseConstraints = constraints.copy(
            minWidth = 0,
            minHeight = 0
        )

        // Don't constrain child views further, measure them with given constraints
        // List of measured children
        val placeables = measurables.map { measurable ->
            // Measure each child
            measurable.measure(looseConstraints)
        }

        //  We will use this alignment to set position of our composables
        val measurableAlignment: List<HorizontalAlignment> = measurables.map { measurable ->
            measurable.alignment
        }

        // Track the y co-ord we have placed children up to
        var yPosition = 0

        val totalHeight: Int = placeables.sumOf { it.height }
            .coerceAtLeast(constraints.minHeight)

        val maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth
        
        // Set the size of the layout as big as it can
        layout(maxWidth, totalHeight) {
            // Place children in the parent layout
            placeables.forEachIndexed { index, placeable ->

                val x = when (measurableAlignment[index]) {
                    HorizontalAlignment.Start -> 0
                    HorizontalAlignment.Center -> (maxWidth - placeable.width) / 2
                    HorizontalAlignment.End -> maxWidth - placeable.width
                }

                // Position item on the screen
                placeable.placeRelative(x = x, y = yPosition)

                // Record the y co-ord placed up to
                yPosition += placeable.height
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How you get alignment data is

val measurableAlignment: List = measurables.map { measurable ->
measurable.alignment
}

or you can do it with without extension with

```
val measurableAlignment: List<HorizontalAlignment> = measurables.map { measurable ->
    measurable.parentData as HorizontalAlignment)
}
```

And you call this custom Modifier inside scope as

```
CustomColumnWithScope(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(8.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(250.dp)
        .background(Color.LightGray)
) {

    Text(
        "Align Start",
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color(0xffF44336))
            .horizontalAlign(HorizontalAlignment.Start),
        color = Color.White
    )
    Text(
        "Align Center",
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color(0xff9C27B0))
            .horizontalAlign(HorizontalAlignment.Center),
        color = Color.White
    )
    Text(
        "Align End",
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color(0xff2196F3))
            .horizontalAlign(HorizontalAlignment.End),
        color = Color.White
    )
    Text(
        "Align Start",
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color(0xff8BC34A))
            .horizontalAlign(HorizontalAlignment.Start),
        color = Color.White
    )
}
```

You can find more examples about scoped `Modifiers`, `Layout`, `Measurables`, `Constraints` and layout properties in this tutorial.

https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials/blob/master/Tutorial1-1Basics/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/tutorial1_1basics/chapter3_layout/Tutorial3_3_1ScopeAndParentDataModifier.kt