How to set negative offset to a row
I am trying to set offset of -16.dp to a row which is in a column which has padding 16.dp
Just to demonstrate, I have a column which has 16.dp padding start and end, I placed a Row above the column which fill the entire width of the screen but the same row within the column with offset -16.dp does not fill the entire width.
but does not work, could you please suggest what am I doing wrong here please
Thanks in advance
R

    Column {
            AnimatedVisibility(visible = homeScreenState.notify is AutoRefreshing || homeScreenState.notify is ManualRefreshing) {
                LinearProgressIndicator(
                    modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                )
            }
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(
                        brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                            colors = listOf(
                                Color.White,
                                Color.Black
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    .defaultMinSize(minHeight = 42.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            ) {

            }
            Column(
                modifier = modifier
                    .background(
                        brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                            colors =
                            listOf(
                                md_theme_night_dream_start,
                                md_theme_night_dream_end
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                    .padding(
//                        vertical = 16.dp,
//                        horizontal = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.margin_horizontal_small),
                        top = 16.dp,
                        start = 16.dp,
                        bottom = 16.dp,
                        end = 16.dp
                    )
            )
            {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(
                            brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                                colors = listOf(
                                    Color.White,
                                    Color.Black
                                )
                            )
                        )
                        .defaultMinSize(minHeight = 42.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .offset(x = -16.dp)
                ) {

                }


You are assigning Modifier.offset() after Modifier.background() due to fact that it's applied to Modifiers after offset, not background, or Composables inside Row you won't be able to have any effect for background but composables inside Row will be offset as they should be.
If you add a Text or any composable inside Row it will be more clear to see changing order of offset and background changes how Composables and Modifiers in chain are effected.
@Preview
@Composable
fun Test() {
    Column {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(
                    brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                        colors = listOf(
                            Color.White,
                            Color.Black
                        )
                    )
                )
                .defaultMinSize(minHeight = 42.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {

        }
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(
                    brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                        colors =
                        listOf(
                            Color.Red,
                            Color.Green
                        )
                    )
                )
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .padding(
//                        vertical = 16.dp,
//                        horizontal = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.margin_horizontal_small),
                    top = 16.dp,
                    start = 16.dp,
                    bottom = 16.dp,
                    end = 16.dp
                )
        )
        {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .border(2.dp, Color.Blue)
                    .offset(x = (-16).dp)
                    .background(
                        brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                            colors = listOf(
                                Color.White,
                                Color.Black
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    .border(3.dp, Color.Magenta)
                    .defaultMinSize(minHeight = 42.dp)

            ) {
                Text("Hello World", modifier = Modifier.background(Color.White))
            }
        }
    }
}

Results as

As you can see Text inside Row is moved to left by 16.dp. Blue border before offset is where it should be since it's before offset and offset is applied to magenta border and background since they are after offset.
Edit
You can increase Constraints of a Composable using Modifier.layout or Modifier.requiredX modifiers. In cases where you need to add fixed size like 16.dp on each side Modifier.layout is what you should use.
@Preview
@Composable
fun Test() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(16.dp).border(2.dp, Color.Blue)
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(
                    brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                        colors = listOf(
                            Color.White,
                            Color.Black
                        )
                    )
                )
                .defaultMinSize(minHeight = 42.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {

        }
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(
                    brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                        colors =
                        listOf(
                            Color.Red,
                            Color.Green
                        )
                    )
                )
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .padding(
                    top = 16.dp,
                    start = 16.dp,
                    bottom = 16.dp,
                    end = 16.dp
                )
        )
        {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .defaultMinSize(minHeight = 42.dp)
                    .layout { measurable, constraints ->
                        val padding = 32.dp.roundToPx()
                        val wrappedConstraints =
                            constraints.copy(
                                minWidth = constraints.maxWidth + padding,
                                maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth + padding
                            )
                        val placeable = measurable.measure(wrappedConstraints)

                        layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                            placeable.placeRelative(0, 0)
                        }
                    }
                    .background(
                        brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(
                            colors = listOf(
                                Color.White,
                                Color.Black
                            )
                        )
                    )

            ) {
                Text("Hello World", modifier = Modifier.background(Color.White))
            }
        }
    }
}

Result

In this image i added border to root Composable to show that we increase it to its dimensions.

Hi thank you for responding, I am a bit unclear on what needs, I have tried to edit the order but the not getting the desired result, could you share the code order please

@BRDroid you can check the sample above. If you check borders, background and Text inside Row you will see that for some Modifiers order matters.

how can I push it to the right as well please?

Sure you can. You need to set order of Modifiers

I was thinking offset(x = (-16).dp) to row will push it to left and right? but it has taken effect of left but not right?

If it pushes left and right at the same doesn't it mean it won't move anywhere? By setting negative offset you move Modifiers after offset and child composable to left by 16.dp. If you use positive number you push right by 16.dp

but how can we push left and right at the same time?, if I use .offset(x=16.dp) it moves to right and if I replace it with .offset(x=-16.dp) it moves to left, but how to do them both at the same time please?

Then you don't need offset. Modifier.padding(horizontal=16.dp) would suffice to limit usable area of Composable or next Modifier by on each side.

if I apply padding on start and end, it will push them inside 16.dp, but what I want it push this row out on start and end so it flush with the screen

apologies and thank you so much for your help on this,

If you want to push it out then use Modifier.layout. It can also be achieved

than you will try that

You can check edit section. With layout you can increase dimensons of Composables more than parent allows. You can refer this answer for more details about how size and Constraints work in Jetpack Compose. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73316247/5457853
