Why are subsequent Modifier.width() calls ignored?
Let's say I have:
Box(
    Modifier
      .background(Color.Red)
      .height(100.dp)
      .width(100.dp)
      .width(600.dp)
  )

I'd expect based on Modifier chaining this would of showed a 100x600 red box, but it's always width(100.dp).
If I tried
Box(
    Modifier
      .background(Color.Red)
      .height(100.dp)
      .width(100.dp)
      .fillMaxWidth()
  )

it'll still stay a 100x100dp red box and I'm not sure why..
I know how to get around this issue of course, but I'm just trying to learn why this happens.
I was expecting the box to be the last modifier width call I made in the chain.

Size Modifiers use Constraints which is an interval to measure Composables basically, from parent or previous modifier  and depending on their logic this min/max width and height is constrained with size modifiers or widened with requiredSize or wrapContent modifiers. You can refer this answer for more details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65779226/android-jetpack-compose-width-height-size-modifier-vs-requiredwidth-requir/73316247#73316247

None of the size modifiers are ignored in any size Modifiers chaining but calculation is done via internal logic.
When we assign size Modifiers we do't actually assign any size. We pass Constraints from parent or previous size Modifier in the chain.
Constraints has min-max ranges for width and height depending on this interval Composable size is measured.
On Modifier.size/width/height/sizeIn/widthIn/heightIn modifiers use function below to calculate range to measure your Composable which is Constraints. When you assign Modifier.wdidth(100.dp).size(600.dp)
Constraints assigned with 600.dp is otherConstraints here, and min and max comes from current size, in your case from Modifier.width(100.dp), results 600.coerceIn(100, 100) returns 100 that's why the first one is used.
/**
 * Takes [otherConstraints] and returns the result of coercing them in the current constraints.
 * Note this means that any size satisfying the resulting constraints will satisfy the current
 * constraints, but they might not satisfy the [otherConstraints] when the two set of constraints
 * are disjoint.
 * Examples (showing only width, height works the same):
 * (minWidth=2, maxWidth=10).constrain(minWidth=7, maxWidth=12) -> (minWidth = 7, maxWidth = 10)
 * (minWidth=2, maxWidth=10).constrain(minWidth=11, maxWidth=12) -> (minWidth=10, maxWidth=10)
 * (minWidth=2, maxWidth=10).constrain(minWidth=5, maxWidth=7) -> (minWidth=5, maxWidth=7)
 */
fun Constraints.constrain(otherConstraints: Constraints) = Constraints(
    minWidth = otherConstraints.minWidth.coerceIn(minWidth, maxWidth),
    maxWidth = otherConstraints.maxWidth.coerceIn(minWidth, maxWidth),
    minHeight = otherConstraints.minHeight.coerceIn(minHeight, maxHeight),
    maxHeight = otherConstraints.maxHeight.coerceIn(minHeight, maxHeight)
)

fillX modifiers without vertical scroll return 0, Constraints.maxWidth range but since you limit range to 100.dp in second example size is coerced in min and max of 100.dp which is 100.dp
And more details about how Constraints work, how size Modifiers check which range to apply for returning Constraints which modifier returns which Constraints you can refer this answer.

coerceIn function checks if your number is in the range specified if it's in that range returns that number. If your number is below min it returns min if it's above max it returns max
