# how to add space between grid items in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am currently trying to implement a gridview, it consists of 2 columns. I know i can implement my own grid view using columns and rows, but i just want to use existing approach although it is experimental.

```
@Composable
fun MyGridScreen() {
    LazyVerticalGrid(cells = GridCells.Fixed(2), modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),contentPadding = PaddingValues(12.dp)) {
        items(15) {
            Box(
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(10.dp)
                    .height(80.dp)
                    .background(Color.Red)
                    .aspectRatio(1f)

            ) {
                Text("Grid item $it", color = Color.White)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the result i achieved. I can't put space below the item :(

[image]

Comment: You can add margin bottom/top in cell

Comment: There's no margin in Jetpack compose. However I think it is because the API is still experimental. Implement your own while it is unstable

Answer (score 65):

You need to set `verticalArrangement` and `horizontalArrangement` properties on the `LazyVerticalGrid` composable.

This will space the items by 10.dp in both the vertical and horizontal axis.

```
 @Composable
    fun MyGridScreen() {
        LazyVerticalGrid(
           cells = GridCells.Fixed(2),
           modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
           contentPadding = PaddingValues(12.dp), 
           verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp), 
           horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp
         ) {
              items(15) {
                 Box(
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(10.dp)
                        .height(80.dp)
                        .background(Color.Red)
                        .aspectRatio(1f)

                ) {
                    Text("Grid item $it", color = Color.White)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `LazyVerticalGrid` doesn't have `verticalArrangement` or `horizontalArrangement`.

Comment: @Ralgha You may combine cell padding + grid contentPadding for spacedBy emulation

Comment: @Ralgha What version of compose are you using? `LazyVerticalGrid` has `verticalArrangement` and `horizontalArrangement` used for cell spacing

Comment: I'm using 1.0.1.

Comment: this answer should checked as correct answer

Comment: In `1.0.5` I don't see `verticalArrangement` or `horizontalArrangement` available.  But they appear in `1.1.0-beta04` .

Answer (score 4):

Padding is exactly what you need in this case. But you need to understand that in compose modifiers order means a lot. By moving `background`  modifier in between padding and sizes modifiers, you'll get what you need. And clickable ripple will work the same.

Check out more how modifiers order works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65698101/3585796

```
.padding(10.dp)
.background(Color.Red)
.height(80.dp)
.aspectRatio(1f)
```

[image]

p.s. if you need your items to be a square, just put your box in one more box. Looks like `width` of items in `LazyVerticalGrid` gets overridden by the grid to fill max width, not sure if that's a bug or a feature.

Comment: Doesn't make much sense

Comment: I've faced this thing before in an app. Weird

Comment: @MARSK check out this answer, it's a good explanation how does modifiers work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65698101/3585796

Comment: setting padding for spacing will also add extra space oh the edge of LazyVerticalGrid

Comment: @Philip Dukhov I mean spacing between edges item's and middle item's are not equal because middle item space is made up by two padding but edge's just have one

Comment: @Vahid I see what you mean, but if you make `contentPadding` equal to `padding` the spacing will be the same