# How to remove padding from Text button?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-button, android-jetpack-compose-button

I am trying to remove padding from `TextButton` but it wont work.

```kotlin
TextButton(
    onClick = {},
    modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp)
) {
    Text(
        " ${getString(R.string.terms_and_conditions)}",
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
        fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.poppins_regular)),
        fontSize = 10.sp,
    )
}
```

I have tried setting the `height` and `size` in `Modifier` property as well but the padding is still present

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot reduce padding with the `padding` modifier: it always adds an extra padding on top of the existing padding. See [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65698101/3585796) for more details about the order of modifiers.

You can reduce `TextButton` padding with `contentPadding` argument, by specifying `PaddingValues(0.dp)`, but this will not fully remove the padding.

If you need fully remove the padding, you can use the `clickable` modifier instead:

```
Text(
    "getString(R.string.terms_and_conditions",
    color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
    fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.neris_semi_bold)),
    fontSize = 10.sp,
    modifier = Modifier
        .clickable {
            // onClick()
        }
)
```

If you want to change the color of the ripple, as is done in `TextButton`, you can do it as follows:

```
.clickable(
    interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    indication = rememberRipple(color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary),
) {
    
}
```

Comment: Adding the `.clickable` modifier to the `Text` composable still didn't remove the padding for me.

Answer (score 30):

Wrap the `TextButton` with `CompositionLocalProvider` to override the value of `LocalMinimumTouchTargetEnforcement`. This will only remove the extra margin but will not modify the defaultMinSize which is hardcoded.

```
CompositionLocalProvider(
    LocalMinimumTouchTargetEnforcement provides false,
) {
    TextButton(
        onClick = {},
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(),
    ) {
        Text(
            "Button",
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
            fontSize = 10.sp,
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: `TextButton` is using the `Button` which wraps the content with a `Surface` which inside adds a `modifier.minimumTouchTargetSize()`. This modifier uses `LocalMinimumTouchTargetEnforcement`. Have a look here https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material/material/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/Surface.kt;drc=2c48dd3399eeb0cfdcc9a16978692a8cb9775f96;l=216

Comment: Indeed, missed that one. This still won't remove the padding completely, only the difference between `ButtonDefaults.MinHeight` and `minimumTouchTargetSize.height`.

Comment: You can pass `Modifier.defaultMinSize(minHeight = 1.dp)` to override the default minimum of `Button` which would otherwise be applied.

Comment: This might also be of interest to others: setting `LocalMinimumTouchTargetEnforcement` to `false` does not necessarily remove the appropriately-sized touch target; it simply doesn't _enforce_ an empty visual area to overlap with a larger touch target. If you don't want to padding for layout purposes, but you place the buttons near a border of a component with sufficient padding, the touch target will still overlap with this padding of the other component.

Answer (score 11):

You can achieve it changing the `contentPadding` and applying a fixed size:

```
TextButton(
    onClick = {},
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp),
    modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp).width(40.dp)
) {
    Text(
        "Button",
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
        fontSize = 10.sp,
    )
}
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

If you come across unwanted margins. When you use onclick in any Button function, it sets propagateMinConstraints = true inside the view's surface - this will apply to unwanted margins. Example how solve this problem:

```
@Composable
fun ButtonWithoutOuterPadding(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    shape: Shape = RectangleShape,
    elevation: Dp = 0.dp,
    color: Color = Color.Transparent,
    border: BorderStroke? = null,
    contentAlignment: Alignment = Alignment.Center,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Box(
        modifier
            .shadow(elevation, shape, clip = false)
            .then(if (border != null) Modifier.border(border, shape) else Modifier)
            .background(
                color = color,
                shape = shape
            )
            .clip(shape)
            .then(
                Modifier.clickable(
                    interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                    indication = LocalIndication.current,
                    enabled = true,
                    onClickLabel = null,
                    role = null,
                    onClick = onClick
                )
            ),
        contentAlignment = contentAlignment,
        propagateMinConstraints = false
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```