# How to remove or reduce padding in Jetpack compose OutlinedButton

Tags: android, material-ui, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-button

Unable to reduce the huge padding in OutlinedButton. Tried contentPadding, modifier padding, etc. Cannot reduce padding for text "apple". Any idea? Should I use any other type of compose component for this?

```
OutlinedButton(     
    onClick = {},       
    border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.White),
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp),
    modifier = Modifier 
        .background(bgColor)
        .height(24.dp)      
        .padding(all = 0.dp),
    colors = ButtonDefaults.outlinedButtonColors(backgroundColor = bgColor)) {
        Text("apple",   
            color = Color.White,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
            modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp).padding(vertical = 0.dp), //.background(bgColor),
        )               
    }
```

Updated after @liveAnyway's answer (thanks!) which appeared to help. After that I removed height from OutlinedButton too - ideally I wanted it like "wrap-content". Once I made that change, I still see the padding. Bottomline I don't want any absolute height specified so that it can work with different font size from system settings.

```
Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 12.dp)) {
    OutlinedButton( 
        onClick = {}, 
        border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.White),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(18.dp),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp),
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(bgColor)
            .padding(all = 0.dp),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.outlinedButtonColors(backgroundColor = bgColor)
    ) {             
        Text("apple",   
            color = Color.White,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 0.dp),
        )               
    }               
}
```

[image]

Comment: Remove `height(10.dp)` modifier setting in `Text`.

Comment: thanks, @liveAnyway. That helped. However I still see padding once I remove all absolute height values, any idea?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`Button` has [default min size](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/a6962db4272f4cb988c2047b04625eb929e716e4/compose/material/material/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/Button.kt#L308) modifier. This is done according to Material guidelines, so that the button is easy to hit. If the control size is too small, the user may have problems hitting it, take this into account when changing this parameter.

You can override it by applying `defaultMinSize` modifier. The `0.dp` will be ignored, but starting from `1.dp` you will get the desired result:

```
OutlinedButton(
    onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(),
    modifier = Modifier
        .defaultMinSize(minWidth = 1.dp, minHeight = 1.dp)
) {
    Text(
        "Apple",
    )
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can design your own button without these restrictions:

```
Surface(
    onClick = {

    },
    shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
    color = bgColor,
    contentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
    border = ButtonDefaults.outlinedBorder,
    role = Role.Button,
) {
    Text(
        "Apple",
    )
}
```

Comment: There still will be additional padding around the button. To remove it completely check https://stackoverflow.com/a/70031001/1502079

Comment: Wow.  Just wow.  Why would someone code something that silently ignores defaultMinSize of 0.dp but allows 1.dp, which for all intents and purposes has the same problem?  This wasted an hour of my time.

Comment: useless, there are invisible paddings!!

Answer (score 21):

You have to change the `minHeight` (default size are `MinWidth = 64.dp` and `MinHeight = 36.dp`) and remove the contentPadding with `contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp)`:

```
 OutlinedButton(
        onClick = {},
        border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.White),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp),
        modifier = Modifier.defaultMinSize(
                minWidth = ButtonDefaults.MinWidth,
                minHeight = 10.dp
         )
    ) {
        Text(
            "apple",
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2
        )
    }
```

[image]