# Rotation animation not working in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-animation, android-jetpack-compose

I tried animations in Jetpack Compose. I'm facing problem in rotate animation.

It seems everything fine. But don't know why it's not working.

My code:

```
     @Composable
    private fun RotateAnimationContent() {
        val isRotated = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
        val rotationAngle by animateFloatAsState(
            targetValue = if (isRotated.value) 360F else 0F,
            animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 1500,easing = FastOutLinearInEasing)

        )
        Column {
            Box(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Red).size(100.dp).rotate(rotationAngle))
            Button(
                onClick = { isRotated.value = !isRotated.value },
                modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
            ) {
                Text(text = "Rotate Box")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the `.rotate(rotationAngle)` as the first modifier of the `Box`. Before background and size.

```kotlin
Column {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.rotate(rotationAngle).background(Color.Red).size(100.dp))
    Button(
        onClick = { isRotated.value = !isRotated.value },
        modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
    ) {
        Text(text = "Rotate Box")
    }
}
```

Check [this very detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65698101/16279195) to better understand why the order of modifiers matters.