# Why is the box is not rotated if I use rotate as the last modifier?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

It does not work:

```
     Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
   
      Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(100.dp)
                .background(color = Color.Red)
                .rotate(45f)
        )
    }
```

It works:

```
       Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
    
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .rotate(45f)
                    .size(100.dp)
                    .background(color = Color.Red)
            )
        }
```

Can anyone please explain how changing the chain of modifier worked here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jetpack Compose - Order of Modifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64206648/jetpack-compose-order-of-modifiers)