# Compose RoundedCornerShape, padding and background colour not working as expected

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

**Expectation**

[image]

**Reality**

[image]

(Please ignore the exact colours;
Outer background colour is purple and inner background colour is red)

Compose code

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable
fun MyCta() {
    MaterialTheme() {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(50))
                .padding(32.dp)
                .background(MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
        ) {
            Text(
                "Tap to continue",
                Modifier
                    .padding(8.dp)
                    .background(Color.Red)
                ,
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Is my expectation off and why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want to use the `padding` after you have specified the `background`

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun MyCta() {
    MaterialTheme() {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(50))
                .background(MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
                .padding(32.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                "Tap to continue",
                Modifier
                    .padding(8.dp)
                    .background(Color.Red)
                ,
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary
            )
        }
    }
}
```

> Note: The explicit order helps you to reason about how different
> modifiers will interact. Compare this to the view-based system where
> you had to learn the box model, that margins applied "outside" the
> element but padding "inside" it, and a background element would be
> sized accordingly. The modifier design makes this kind of behavior
> explicit and predictable, and gives you more control to achieve the
> exact behavior you want.

Modifiers [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts#modifiers):

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
            RoundedCornerShape(50))
        .padding(32.dp)
)
```

You have to apply the `padding` modifier after the `background`.
It is important the [order of modifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64206648/jetpack-compose-order-of-modifiers).

[image]