# How to remove RadioButton's padding in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a problem with RadioButton component in my Jetpack Compose application. I have some RadioButtons with text and this have a lot of padding by default. Can I remove this padding or to set a custom padding to avoid a lot of space between each?

Currently I have this:

[image]

My code is:

```
Column {
    MyEnum.values().filter { rb -> rb.visible }.forEach { rb ->
        Row(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = 0.dp, vertical = 0.dp)
                .clickable(
                    interactionSource = interactionSource,
                    indication = null
                ) {
                    TODO()
                },
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            RadioButton(
                selected = (rb.position == selectedOption),
                onClick = {
                    TODO()
                },
                colors = RadioButtonDefaults.colors(
                    selectedColor = DialogOutlinedTextFocus,
                    unselectedColor = DialogOutlinedTextUnfocus
                )
            )
    
            Text(
                text = stringResource(id = rb.idText),
                color = Color.Black,
                fontSize = 14.sp,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(horizontal = 3.dp, vertical = 2.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I tried with contentPadding, but this property does not exist in RadioButton component.

Comment: This line `padding(horizontal = 0.dp, vertical = 0.dp)` just has no effect. Each padding modifier adds padding to the current modifiers set, see more details in [why modifiers order matters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64206648/jetpack-compose-order-of-modifiers). Suggested answer is the only way to override default element padding.

Comment: if set `onClick` then changed Modifier, so you can set `onClick = null` and set clickable for radio button parent

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The source code for `RadioButton.kt` sets the padding modifier at line 108. With modifiers, order matters. Even if you provide your own padding modifier it will be overridden by line 108.

[image: RadioButton.kt]

The sizing values are hardcoded at the bottom of the file.

[image: RadioButton.kt]

If you really want to "reduce the padding", apply a `size` modifier. I use `20.dp` because it's equal to `radioButtonSize` in `RadioButton.kt` so the button doesn't get clipped. This should work for your purposes since the entire row is clickable.

```
RadioButton(
    modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp),
    selected = selected,
    onClick = { TODO() },
)
```

[image: Preview]

Although, you're probably better off in the long term making custom components you can control. Luckily, the source code is ready available. Just copy, paste and adjust to your needs.

Comment: I think the "padding" is caused by both of the hard coded `RadioButtonSize` and `RadioButtonPadding`

Answer (score 2):

[@Thracian answer's about checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71609165/7503613) works also with RadioButton

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalMinimumInteractiveComponentEnforcement provides false) {
    RadioButton(
        selected = selected,
        onClick = {...},
    )
}
```

Comment: This is a way better answer compared to the accepted answer, it is a "non-hacky" way to achieve what's required.

Answer (score 1):

You could specify the Row height in the Row.Modifier
like this:

```
 Row(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        //HERE YOU GO
        .height(30.dp)                
        .padding(horizontal = 0.dp, vertical = 0.dp)
```