# Remove Default padding around checkboxes in Jetpack Compose new update

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In the new update of jetpack compose , a default padding space will be provided around the touchables as said in official documentation.
[Refer this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fO5GF.png)

Please help how to avoid this and to implement this "set LocalMinimumTouchTargetEnforcement to false " and where to do this?

Comment: Accessibility is very important. Why should you avoid it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to provide it with `CompositionLocalProvider`

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalMinimumInteractiveComponentEnforcement provides false) {
    Checkbox(
        checked = checked,
        onCheckedChange = {
            checked = it
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: For LocalMinimumTouchTargetEnforcement: This material API is experimental and is likely to change or to be removed in the future.

Comment: @Thracian Hey where did you get this from? can you share doc for this?

Answer (score 6):

Try that:

```kotlin
Checkbox(modifier = Modifier.absoluteOffset((-12).dp, 0.dp))
```

Comment: -12 is hardcoded. Noone knows what how default padding will be changed in future

Answer (score 5):

For Material 3, the equivalent to [Thracian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71609165/2030092) (thanks for leading me in the right direction!) would be:

```
CompositionLocalProvider(LocalMinimumInteractiveComponentEnforcement provides false) {
   Checkbox(
       checked = checked,
       onCheckedChange = {
           checked = it
       }
   )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set Modifier.size(20.dp).

20.dp is checkbox size without paddings.
With this fixed size, ripple effect still exist and looks good.

```
Checkbox(
    modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp),
    checked = checkBoxState,
    onCheckedChange = { isChecked ->
        checkBoxState = isChecked
    })
```