# How remove default padding in Button Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In View (MaterialButton) usually use this :

```
android:insetTop="0dp"
android:insetBottom="0dp"
```

Is there a substitute for inset in Jetpack Compose Button?

Comment: It's because of accessibility. Minimum touch target is 48.dp for Composables. You can check out answer here https://stackoverflow.com/q/72869987/5457853

Answer (score 1):

Try it like so:

```
Button(
    onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
    //This is important:
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp)
) {

}
```

Comment: I've tried, but it doesn't work

Comment: Post what you tried and your result as image, and your expected result as image if possible

Answer (score 0):

All Compose components are made according to Material metrics. If you want to customize them in the best way, see how the Button element is made. Just hold `Ctrl` and click on the `Button`.