# How to remove the gaps at the top and bottom of buttons in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to

1. stack two buttons on top of each other with no gap in-between,
2. while also leaving the content-based height scaling intact.

As shown in the MWE below, I can do these things individually, but not at the same time. I have googled and played around with stuff like `padding` and `contentPadding` a fair bit, but that didn't get me anywhere closer to finding the cause of this gap.

[image: Screenshot]

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@Composable
fun TwoButtonsWithHeight() {
    Column() {
        Button(onClick = {}, modifier = Modifier.height(40.dp)) { Text("Button 1") }
        Button(onClick = {}, modifier = Modifier.height(40.dp)) { Text("Button 2") }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun TwoButtonsWithHeightPreview() {
    TwoButtonsWithHeight()
}

@Composable
fun TwoButtonsWithoutHeight() {
    Column() {
        Button(onClick = {}, modifier = Modifier) { Text("Button 1") }
        Button(onClick = {}, modifier = Modifier) { Text("Button 2") }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun TwoButtonsWithoutHeightPreview() {
    TwoButtonsWithoutHeight()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add padding in `Column` in your `TwoButtonsWithHeight` like this:

```
@Composable
fun TwoButtonsWithHeight() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 10.dp, bottom = 10.dp)) {
        Button(onClick = {}, modifier = Modifier.height(40.dp)) { Text("Button 1") }
        Button(onClick = {}, modifier = Modifier.height(40.dp)) { Text("Button 2") }
    }
}
```

this will result like this:

[image: TwoButtons]

**Edit**

You are getting extra padding from `Button` itself because android wants to keep some minimum distance to make some elements touchable.
More you can read here: [default padding around the touchables](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/accessibility)

this you can remove by  `LocalMinimumInteractiveComponentEnforcement`

More you can read here: [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#LocalMinimumTouchTargetEnforcement())

```
fun TwoButtonsWithoutHeight() {
    Column() {
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalMinimumTouchTargetEnforcement provides false){
            Button(onClick = {}, modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp)) { Text("Button 1") }
        }
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalMinimumTouchTargetEnforcement provides false){
            Button(onClick = {}, modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp)) { Text("Button 1") }
        }
    }
}
```

You will get your result from this
Hope this helps!!

Comment: Sorry if my question was badly worded, but what I want is an output without gaps  while having automatic height ENABLED, meaning WITHOUT the `Modifier.height(40.dp)`. Anyway,I tried adding your padding in my `TwoButtonsWithoutHeight`, and it didn't affect the gap between the buttons, just added more space at the top and bottom.

Comment: @MaxD, got your problem. I have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72870364/), the gap is caused by accessibility settings. In any case, this seems to do the trick:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun TwoButtonsWithoutHeight() {
    Column() {
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalMinimumTouchTargetEnforcement provides false) {
            Button(onClick = {}, modifier = Modifier) { Text("Button 1") }
            Button(onClick = {}, modifier = Modifier) { Text("Button 2") }
        }
    }
}
```