# Buttons have margin in JetPack Compose Desktop

Tags: kotlin, desktop-application

I've noticed a small issue with buttons in JetPack compose. They seem to have some kind of margin, and I have no idea of how I could get rid of that. Here's an example:

```java
@Preview
@Composable
fun testMain() {
    Column {
        Button(onClick = {}, modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.Red)) {
            Text("Text", modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.Green))
        }
        Text("Text 2", modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.Green))
        Text("Text 3", modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.Green))
    }
}
```

which results in this:

[image: JetPack preview]

As you can see, the button seems to have some kind of padding (marked in red), which pushes other content down.

Is there a way to get rid of that padding? I have tried to use the `.padding(0.dp)` modifier, but that did nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's because of accessibility. Most of  Composables have minimum 48.dp height and with to be compliant with minimum touch size. You can see these questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72869987/jetpack-compose-button-padding-outside-of-border-why?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71609051/remove-default-padding-around-checkboxes-in-jetpack-compose-new-update/71609165#71609165 `CompositionLocalProvider(LocalMinimumTouchTargetEnforcement provides false)` removes padding around Button, CheckBox, Switch and others that have this minimum size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Button()` composable has – as many other provided composables - its *default minimal and maximal width and height.*

You may replace the minimal and/or maximal default button height by `heightIn()` (= height in range) modifier:

```
Button(
    onClick = {},
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(color = Color.Red)
        .heightIn(max = 35.dp)            // <--- this is added
) { ...
```

(I changed your code style to the more common one.)

But the default button shape has rounded corners, so there will be still some red color of background near them:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!

The round border is fine, it was just for marking purposes, to see the dimensions of the button exactly.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider voting my answer up, if it was helpful for you.