# Jetpack Compose wrapContentHeight/ heightIn is adding aditional space around the buttons

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am learning Jetpack Compose, and I've created a few set of buttons as a practice.

This is the button

```
@Composable
fun MyButton(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    isEnabled: Boolean = true,
    onClick: () -> Unit,
) {

        Button(
            enabled = isEnabled,
            onClick = { onClick() },
            modifier = modifier.width(270.dp).wrapContentHeight(),
        ) {
            Text(
                text = text,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.button
            )
        }
    
}
```

The problem is, that if i set the height of the button to `wrapContentHeight` or use `heightIn` with different max and min values, compose automatically adds a space around the button as seen here

[image: preview button wrapContentHeight]

But if i remove WrapContent, and use a fixed height, or define same min and max height for `heightIn` this probblem does not appear

```
@Composable
fun MyButton(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    isEnabled: Boolean = true,
    onClick: () -> Unit,
) {

        Button(
            enabled = isEnabled,
            onClick = { onClick() },
            modifier = modifier.width(270.dp).height(36.dp),
        ) {
            Text(
                text = text,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.button
            )
        }

}
```

[image: preview fixed height]

And this is the code used for the column/preview of the functions:

```
@Composable
private fun SampleScreen() {
    MyTheme{
        Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.background,){
            Column(
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp, Alignment.CenterVertically),
                modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp)
            ) {
                var isEnabled by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

                MyButton("Enable/Disable") {
                    isEnabled = !isEnabled
                }
                MyButton("Button") {}
                MyButton(text = "Disabled Button", isEnabled = isEnabled) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even if I remove the `spacedBy` operator from column the same issue appears.

I have tried to search for an explanation to this, but I did not manage to find anything.

Any help or resource with explanations is appreciated.

Comment: It's because accessibility that default minimum width or height is 48.dp for composables like Button, Switch, CheckBox, Slider and some others. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72869987/jetpack-compose-button-padding-outside-of-border-why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71609051/remove-default-padding-around-checkboxes-in-jetpack-compose-new-update

Comment: @Thracian Omg. Thanks so much. But shouldn't this appear in the layout inspector, or at least the preview boundries as used space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because Minimum dimension of Composables touch area is 48.dp by default for accessibility. However you can override this by using

```
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalMinimumTouchTargetEnforcement provides false) {
     Button(
        enabled = isEnabled,
        onClick = { onClick() },
        modifier = modifier.heightIn(min = 20.dp)
                .widthIn(min = 20.dp),
    ) {
        Text(
            text = text,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.button
        )
    }
}
```

Or something like

```
   Button(modifier = Modifier.absoluteOffset((-12).dp, 0.dp)){
            Text(
                text = text,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.button
            )
        }
```