# How to add a padding to elements inside a Chip without hidding elements inside in wear Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, wear-os

The title isn't very clear but if you try this code, you'll see that there is no text (for isLoading = false).

```
@Composable
fun RefreshButton(
    isLoading: Boolean,
    onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Chip(
        label = {
            if (isLoading) {
                CircularProgressIndicator(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center)
                        .padding(32.dp)
                )
            } else {
                Text(
                    text = "Refresh", modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center)
                    .padding(32.dp)
                )
            }
        },
        onClick = { onClick() },
        modifier = Modifier.width(intrinsicSize = IntrinsicSize.Max)
    )
}
```

It works without the padding but I would like to add some padding.

I use wear compose and wear compose-foundation 1.0.0-alpha20.

Comment: I think (but I am not sure) padding should be applied to Chip, not Text or Indicator.

Answer (score 0):

**My answer below was wrong. Compose components tend to have hardcoded values like `size` and `padding`. This is true for `Chip.kt`. [Here's an answer explaining a related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71850751/6477796.)**

---

> bylazy is correct. You should apply padding to the parent, not the
> content
>
> ```
>     isLoading: Boolean,
>     onClick: () -> Unit) {
>     Chip(
>         label = {
>             if (isLoading) {
>                 CircularProgressIndicator(
>                     modifier = Modifier
>                         .fillMaxSize()
>                         .wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center)
>                 )
>             } else {
>                 Text(
>                     text = "Refresh", modifier = Modifier
>                     .fillMaxSize()
>                     .wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center)
>                 )
>             }
>         },
>         onClick = { onClick() },
>         modifier = Modifier
>            .width(intrinsicSize = IntrinsicSize.Max)
>            .padding(32.dp)
>     ) }
> ```

Comment: It doesn't do what I want. The chip's size is the same. Here's what I get with padding for the chip: https://ibb.co/2gpwCGc
I want to get something like this: https://ibb.co/zGMfYDz .
I notice that when I add padding to elements, the chip's size is ok but the text inside is not visible. Whereas, it doesn't do anything when padding is added to the Chip

Comment: is Chip a component you made? Can I see the code for it? I don't see a compose component Chip in my version of Compose, however, some compose components do hardcode values like height. It could be that

Comment: No, it's from the wear compose library (https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/wear/compose/material/package-summary#Chip(kotlin.Function0,androidx.wear.compose.material.ChipColors,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.ui.semantics.Role,kotlin.Function0)
You're right about the height. There is a default height in the code :
Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .height(ChipDefaults.Height)

Comment: In cases like these, I copy and paste the source code and just make the changes I want. Not ideal, but it works.