# Create Vertical Sliders in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, slider, android-jetpack-compose

I am building an Android App which needs to create several vertical sliders in the same page for music equalizer adjustment, but I can only find horizontal sliders from the official material design documents.

I try to implement default slider from official documents and rotate it with modifier and it works, but the problem is that I am not able to adjust the height now using `Modifier`.

[image: screenshot]

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Row(modifier =
            Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .fillMaxHeight(),
               horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
                slider()
                slider()
                slider()
                slider()
                slider()
                slider()
                slider()

            }

        }
    }
}



@Composable
fun slider() : Int
{
    var sliderPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

    Slider(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(50.dp)
            .height(120.dp)
            .background(color = Color.Red)
            .wrapContentSize()
            .rotate(270F)
            .padding(start = 0.5.dp),

        value = sliderPosition,
        valueRange = 1f..10f,
        onValueChange = {sliderPosition = it}
    )

    return sliderPosition.roundToInt()
}
```

Comment: I recommend using the modifier as the last argument, so that you can omit the comma: then it will be much easier to add/remove/swap modifiers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your rotated slider doesn't fill available height, because it gets a wrong constraint after rotation. To fix this you first of all need to swap `width` and `height` values.

Next, `Modifier.rotate` won't change the view position, so you need to manually update it after rotation. To understand what's going on, you can run the following code:

```
Box(
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    Box(Modifier
        .size(100.dp, 50.dp)
        .border(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Red)
        .rotate(90f)
        .background(Color.Green))
}
```

It'll produce the following view:

[image]

As you can see, real view frame is shown with the red border, and your view has an unexpected offset.

To fix it, you can use `Modifier.layout`: you need to swap constraints and result view size dimensions, and revert the offset.

Also I'm using `Modifier.graphicsLayer` with `transformOrigin` set to zero point, so it's easier to calculate an offset needed in `Modifier.layout`.

And the last part, size modifier should be placed after `Modifier.layout`, in order to get parent view constraints instead of this static ones during `layout`. And `layout` should be placed after rotation. Check out more about why modifiers order matters in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65698101/3585796)

Final modifier for your slider:

```
Modifier
    .graphicsLayer {
        rotationZ = 270f
        transformOrigin = TransformOrigin(0f, 0f)
    }
    .layout { measurable, constraints ->
        val placeable = measurable.measure(
            Constraints(
                minWidth = constraints.minHeight,
                maxWidth = constraints.maxHeight,
                minHeight = constraints.minWidth,
                maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight,
            )
        )
        layout(placeable.height, placeable.width) {
            placeable.place(-placeable.width, 0)
        }
    }
    .width(120.dp)
    .height(50.dp)
```

Comment: Thanks Philip,  this fixed my problem. 
But now I have another issue,  I need 2 labels, one on the top and the other on the bottom of the slider. If I set a fixed width value in modifier like this `.width(180.dp)
  `, it will be fine. https://imgur.com/a/DmV6rYO

However I would like to let the slider height responsive to the device screen size, so I set the width like this `.fillMaxWidth()` in modifier, the bottom label will disappear. 
https://imgur.com/a/QMRys5i
Is there any ways to fix this? Thanks so much!

Comment: @SioChung use `Modifier.weight(1f)` instead of `fillMaxWidth()`

Comment: There seems no `.weight()` available in Slider compose.

Comment: @SioChung it should be available inside `Row`, how else are you adding the text views?

Comment: @SioChung I mean a column ofc. You can define your slider to be used only inside a column, with `fun ColumnScope.slider()`, or pass modifier as a parameter

Comment: Hi Philip, I tried to set in `Row` but still not working.  I try to elaborate my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71167811/16755472) to show how I add the text views.

Comment: What if you need to flip it? I've been trying to achieve this and failed (using rotationY). Basically i need the default slider rotated to vertical, but starting with 0 at the top, not the bottom. I fixed forcing RTL direction, but there has to be a better way.

Comment: @Alejandra you need `rotationZ = 90f` and `placeable.place(0, -placeable.height)`, try creating a sample view with a couple of separate sliders that are attached to `rotationZ`/`placeable.place` offset, to see and understand how changing these values work