# Create vertical slider with label in Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I made a vertical slider based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71129399/16755472), and now I need to add title and  value for each sliders.

If I set a fixed width value in modifier like this `modifier.width(180.dp)`, it looks fine like this [image]

However I would like to let the slider height be responsive to the device screen size, so I set the width to `modifier.fillMaxWidth()`, the bottom text will disappear [image: disappear]

Here is my vertical slider compose looks like, and I try to set the height in modifier here.

```
@Composable
fun VerticalSlider(value: MutableState<Float>, min: Int, max: Int, onFinished:(Int)->Unit) {
    Slider(
        modifier = Modifier
            .graphicsLayer {
                rotationZ = 270f
                transformOrigin = TransformOrigin(0f, 0f)
            }
            .layout { measurable, constraints ->
                val placeable = measurable.measure(
                    Constraints(
                        minWidth = constraints.minHeight,
                        maxWidth = constraints.maxHeight,
                        minHeight = constraints.minWidth,
                        maxHeight = constraints.maxWidth,
                    )
                )
                layout(placeable.height, placeable.width) {
                    placeable.place(-placeable.width, 0)
                }
            }
//            .fillMaxWidth()
            .width(180.dp)
            .height(50.dp)
        ,
        value = value.value,
        valueRange = min.toFloat()..max.toFloat(),
        onValueChange = {
            value.value = it.toInt().toFloat()
        },
        onValueChangeFinished = {
            onFinished(value.value.toInt())
        },
    )
}
```

Vertical slider with text.

```
@Composable
fun VerticalSliderWithText(sliderValue: MutableState<Float>, min: Int, max: Int, onFinished:(Int)->Unit) {
    var sliderValue = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ){
            Text("slider title")
            VerticalSlider(value = sliderValue, min = -6, max = 6,
            ) {
                //println(" finish value: $it")
            }
            Text(modifier = Modifier.background(Green),
                text="slider value")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Modifier.fillMaxWidth`, you need to use [`Modifier.weight`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/ColumnScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).weight(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Boolean)), which is available inside a `Column`. To do so you need to add a modifier parameter:

```
@Composable
fun VerticalSlider(value: MutableState<Float>, min: Int, max: Int, onFinished:(Int)->Unit, modifier: Modifier) {
    Slider(
        modifier = modifier
            //...
```

So you can pass `Modifier.weight` like this:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround,
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
){
    Text("slider title")
    VerticalSlider(
        value = sliderValue,
        min = -6,
        max = 6,
        onFinished = {
            //println(" finish value: $it")
        },
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
    )
```

Alternatively, you can declare `VerticalSlider` on `ColumnScope`, so `Modifier.weight` can be used directly from the function:

```
@Composable
fun ColumnScope.VerticalSlider(value: MutableState<Float>, min: Int, max: Int, onFinished:(Int)->Unit) {
    Slider(
        modifier = Modifier
            .weight(1f)
            //...
```