# Get Thumb position (x, y) of Slider in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-slider

Three sliders are defined in Jetpack Compose and the thumb positions of these three sliders are needed to connect them using a `Path` in a `Canvas` behind them. How to get the position PointF(x,y) of the thumb in each Slider to draw the Path or any other way to achieve this? Below is sample code snippet and image of sample implementation  to achieve.

```
@Composable
fun MySliderDemo() {
    var sliderPosition1 = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var sliderPosition2 = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    var sliderPosition3 = remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

    Slider(value = sliderPosition1.value, onValueChange = { sliderPosition1.value = it })
    Slider(value = sliderPosition2.value, onValueChange = { sliderPosition2.value = it })
    Slider(value = sliderPosition3.value, onValueChange = { sliderPosition3.value = it })
}
```

[image: Sample implementation]

Answer (score 0):

var pos1 by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
var pos2 by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
var pos3 by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

```
var layoutCoordinates = 0

Slider(value = pos1, onValueChangeFinished = { newPos1 ->
    // you now have 3 slider positions:
    // newPos1, pos2, and pos3
}, onValueChange = { pos1 = it },
    modifier = Modifier.onGloballyPositioned {
        layoutCoordinates = it
    })

Slider(value = pos2, onValueChangeFinished = { newPos2 ->
    // you now have 3 slider positions:
    // pos1, newPos2, and pos3
}, onValueChange = { pos2 = it })

Slider(value = pos3, onValueChangeFinished = { newPos3 ->
    // you now have 3 slider positions:
    // pos1, pos2, and newPos3
}, onValueChange = { pos3 = it })
```

with every Slider's `onValueChangeFinished`, you get each of their values. You can also get the `LayoutCoordinates` of the Slider (I assume you only need to get it from one of them since they're all the same size, but if not, you can just keep track of all 3) from `Modifier.onGloballyPositioned`. From there, you should be able to calculate the position of each slider based on the Slider value and the layout coordinates (which give you position, size, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The implementation that I would need to achieve is the other way around. I want to change the path as per the users adjustments of the slider. So I want to know the position of the Thumb in the slider.

Comment: That's exactly what my code does -- when the user moves the slider, onValueChange gets triggered, and adjusts the other 2 sliders

Comment: Sorry, I think my question is not clear. I do not want the user interaction to change the position of the other sliders. I want to get the Thumb position of each slider in order to draw a path using canvas.

Comment: Ok, that's a relatively simple thing to do once you keep track of the 3 slider positions. Updating my answer...

Comment: I have edited sample code to add more clarity.

Comment: I need the positions PointF(x,y) of the Thumbs of all three sliders in order to plot a path.

Comment: As I said in my answer, you can set Modifier.onGloballyPositioned() for all 3 sliders, and keep track of all 3 of them. I just thought that since you know their dimensions, and their values, you could calculate the positions of the other 2 based on the 1st one

Comment: Sorry, the layout co-ordinates do not return the relative position of the Thumb with respect to the display. I require the PointF(x,y) positions of the each Thumb in order to draw a Path using canvas.

Comment: No, but you know the width in px of the slider, and you know the valueRange (presumably, you set it yourself). So, thumbRelativePosX = sliderValue / sliderMaxValue * sliderWidthPx gets you the Thumb's X coordinate relative to the Slider layout. You also have the slider's coordinates (in pixels), so sliderLayoutPositionX + thumbRelativePosX is the Thumb position you're looking for. The same calculation can be done for Y coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can determine the position of an element(thumb) within a component(slider) by finding the start and the end of the component(slider), then by using a fraction of the current progress of the component, you could use [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20linear%20interpolation%20is,set%20of%20known%20data%20points.) to determine the exact position. Values of `offsetStartExtra` and `offsetEndExtra` variables are are based on experiments just to get the thumb axies right, you may want to change them to other values based on your padding, thumb size, parent position, etc. If needed, play around with them until you get it rigth within your layout.

## Slider (Horizontal):

Notice I calculate the end and the start of the slider on `onGloballyPositioned`

```
var sliderValue by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

var start by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
var end by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
var thumbCoordinates by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(16.dp),
) {
    Slider(
        value = sliderValue,
        onValueChange = { newValue ->
            sliderValue = newValue
            // updating the thumbCoordinate using linear interpolation
            thumbCoordinates = start + (end - start) * (sliderValue / maxSliderValue)
        },
        valueRange = minSliderValue..maxSliderValue,
        modifier = Modifier
            .align(Alignment.Center)
            .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                // calculating start and end of the slider
                val posInRoot = coordinates.positionInRoot()

                val offsetStartExtra = Offset(x = -28f, y = 10f)
                start = posInRoot + offsetStartExtra


                val offsetEndExtra = Offset(x = -83f, 10f)
                end = posInRoot.copy(posInRoot.x + coordinates.size.width.toFloat()) + offsetEndExtra
                thumbCoordinates=start + (end - start) * (sliderValue/range.endInclusive)

            }
    )

    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        // using the calculated coordinates here...
        drawRect(color = Color.Red, topLeft = thumbCoordinates, size = Size(24f, 24f))
    }

}
```

### Result:

[image]

### Slider (Vertical)

If you have a vertical slider (check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71129399/16059091)),  then you might need to tweak some things for `start` and `end` variables as well as the offset extras in `onGloballyPositioned` modifier.

```
....
.onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                val posInRoot = coordinates.positionInRoot()

                val startOffsetExtra = Offset(x = 54f, y = -40f)
                start = posInRoot + startOffsetExtra
                
                val endOffsetExtra = Offset(x = 54f, y = 15f)
                end = posInRoot.copy(y = posInRoot.y - coordinates.size.width.toFloat()) + endOffsetExtra
            }
....
```

### Result

[image]

Now for your case, you could draw a line with canvas provding startPoint as position of first thumb, and end point the position of the 2nd thumb, then you could draw another line starting from 2nd thumb and ending on the 3rd. Or you could just draw a path with canvas providing all the thumb's positions.