# Is it possible to round the edges of a row in jetpack?

Tags: user-interface, button, row, android-jetpack-compose

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: This is what I'm trying to do]

So I have created 2 rounded buttons in a row and gave different background colors depending whether they're selected or not. The goal is to create a kind of an illusion of a tab/toggle.

The unselected button will have the same color as the row's background color. Unfortunately, since a row is a rectangle shape there comes a residue space at the corners that still shows the background color .

[image: This is what I'm getting]

[image: How to avoid this]

This is my code for the buttons

```kotlin
val cornerRadius = 20.dp

var selectedIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0)}

val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
val screenWidth = configuration.screenWidthDp.dp

val items = listOf(

    OutlinedButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {

    },

    OutlinedButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {

})

Row(
    modifier = Modifier

        .padding(top = 8.dp)
        .wrapContentHeight()

        .width(screenWidth).background(color = Color.Gray).clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))
) {
  //  Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

        items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->

            OutlinedButton(modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .width(screenWidth/2),


                shape = when (index) {
                    // left outer button
                    0 -> (if (selectedIndex == index) {
                        RoundedCornerShape(
                            topStart = cornerRadius,
                            topEnd = cornerRadius,
                            bottomStart = cornerRadius,
                            bottomEnd = cornerRadius
                        )
                    } else {
                        RoundedCornerShape(
                            topStart = cornerRadius,
                            topEnd = cornerRadius,
                            bottomStart = cornerRadius,
                            bottomEnd = cornerRadius
                        )
                    })

                    //rightouterbutton

                    else -> (if (selectedIndex == index) {
                        RoundedCornerShape(
                            topStart = cornerRadius,
                            topEnd = cornerRadius,
                            bottomStart = cornerRadius,
                            bottomEnd = cornerRadius
                        )
                    }
                            else{RoundedCornerShape(
                        topStart = 0.dp,
                        topEnd = cornerRadius,
                        bottomStart = 0.dp,
                        bottomEnd = cornerRadius
                    )})
                },
                border = BorderStroke(
                    1.dp, if (selectedIndex == index) {
                      Color.Transparent
                    } else {
                        Color.Transparent
                    }
                ),
                colors = if (selectedIndex == index) {
                    // colors when selected
                    ButtonDefaults.outlinedButtonColors(
                        backgroundColor = Color.Yellow,
                        contentColor = Color.Black
                    )
                } else {
                    // colors when not selected
                    ButtonDefaults.outlinedButtonColors(
                        backgroundColor = Color.Gray,
                        contentColor = Color.Black
                    )
                },

                onClick = { selectedIndex = index },

                ) {
                if (index == 0) {

                    Text(
                        text = "In progress",
                        color = if (selectedIndex == index) {
                            Color.Black
                        } else {
                            Color.DarkGray.copy(alpha = 0.9f)
                        },
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
                    )
                } else {


                    Text(
                        text = "Completed",
                        color = if (selectedIndex == index) {
                            MaterialTheme.colors.primary
                        } else {
                            Color.DarkGray.copy(alpha = 0.9f)
                        },
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`Modifier.clip` applied after the `Modifier.background` has no effect in your case, you need to reverse the order. Read more about why the order of modifiers matters in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65698101/3585796)

```
.clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))
.background(color = Color.Gray)
```

Another option in the case of `Modifier.background` is that you can apply the shape specifically to the background color. Note that this solution will not clip other view content to the shape as `Modifier.clip` does.

```
.background(color = Color.Gray, shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp))
```

Comment: This is what, I am looking for! Thanks @Phil it helped me.
Actually giving shape to the background removed unwanted corner space