# How to change the shape of a Row's border in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

### Problem description

How to change the shape of a `Row` border in Jetpack Compose?

I'm creating a custom button in jetpack compose and for that I'm using a `Row` to align the content horizontally. I need this custom button to have the following format:

[image]

However my code in compose renders the following element, without the rounded edges:

[image]

The code for this compose function is below:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun LargeQuantityButton(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onPlusClick: () -> Unit,
    onMinusClick: () -> Unit,
    text: String,
) = Row(
    modifier = modifier
        .border(
            border = ButtonDefaults.outlinedBorder,
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
        ),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
) {
    RemoveIcon(action = onMinusClick)
    Text(
        text = text,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.W400
    )
    AddIcon(action = onPlusClick)
}
```

### My attempt fails

I tried adding the `clip` function call right after the `border` call of the `Modifier` like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun LargeQuantityButton(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onPlusClick: () -> Unit,
    onMinusClick: () -> Unit,
    text: String,
) = Row(
    modifier = modifier
        .border(border = ButtonDefaults.outlinedBorder)
        .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
) {
    RemoveIcon(action = onMinusClick)
    Text(
        text = text,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.W400
    )
    AddIcon(action = onPlusClick)
}
```

But it didn't work either.

Comment: your screenshot looks like from the second code block, the reasons it doesn't work can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71160579/3585796). But the first code block rounds border correctly to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I didn't understand exactly why but when I added a `.padding` after the `Modifier.border` statement the problem was solved:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun LargeQuantityButton(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onPlusClick: () -> Unit,
    onMinusClick: () -> Unit,
    text: String,
) = Row(
    modifier = modifier
        .border(
            border = ButtonDefaults.outlinedBorder,
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
        )
        .padding(PaddingValues(horizontal = 8.dp)),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
) {
    RemoveIcon(action = onMinusClick)
    Text(
        text = text,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.W500
    )
    AddIcon(action = onPlusClick)
}
```

Result:

[image]