# How to make custom tab indicator to be a rounded bar in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

The following picture shows what I want to achieve. I want the tab indicator to be a short rounded bar.

[image: expected]

I looked up the implementation of `TabRowDefaults.Indicator()`, and just made my own one. I just tried to add the `clip()` modifier, but it didn't work. And I tried to change the order of the modifiers, but still no luck.

And here is my code implementation:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TabLayout(
    tabItems: List<String>,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    var tabIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    Column {
        ScrollableTabRow(
            selectedTabIndex = tabIndex,
            edgePadding = 0.dp,
            backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.background,
            contentColor = Blue100,
            indicator = { tabPositions ->
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .tabIndicatorOffset(tabPositions[tabIndex])
                        .height(4.dp)
                        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)) // clip modifier not working
                        .padding(horizontal = 28.dp)
                        .background(color = AnkiBlue100)
                )
            },
            divider = {},
        ) {
            tabItems.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                Tab(
                    selected = tabIndex == index,
                    onClick = { tabIndex = index },
                    selectedContentColor = Blue100,
                    unselectedContentColor = Gray200,
                    text = {
                        Text(text = item, fontFamily = fontOutfit, fontSize = 18.sp)
                    }
                )
            }
        }
        Divider(
            color = Gray50,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(vertical = 4.dp)
        )
        content()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You applied `Modifier.padding` between `Modifier.clip` and `Modifier.background`, so the rounding is actually applied to the transparent padding. You need to move the padding in front of the clip, or specify the shape with the background:

```
.background(color = AnkiBlue100, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
```

Read more about why the order of the modifiers matters in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65698101/3585796)