# How to make Row component whole clickable with padding?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Row component which is not clickable on its whole area because of padding modifier. How can I make this component clickable on whole area with the same padding effect?

```
@Composable
fun UserRow() {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(16.dp)
                .clickable {
                    /* ... */
                }
        ) {
            Icon(
                /* ... */
            )
            Text(
                /* ... */
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change order of padding and clickable.

Comment: Read more about why the order of the modifiers matters in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65698101/3585796)

Answer (score 28):

The `padding` modifier should be the last as shown below.

```kotlin
Row(
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .clickable {
            /* ... */
        }
        .padding(16.dp) ...
)
```