# Jetpack Compose - Scrollable Column and clip to padding

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a simple screen with scrollable vertical column. It contains some text and images.

```kotlin
 Column(
   modifier = Modifier
     .fillMaxWidth()
     .padding(16.dp)
     .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
 ) {
      ...
   }
```

The content is scrollable but it clips to defined padding. Meaning when you scroll, you can see that overscroll shadow does not fill the entire screen, but it is bound to the padding. It looks really bad:

[image]

In XML world you would use `android:clipToPadding="false"` to "fill" the container. Is there equivalent of that in Compose?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Got it, apparently order of modifier constraints matters, didn't know that.
Just place padding as last one.

```kotlin
Column(
   modifier = Modifier
     .fillMaxWidth()
     .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
     .padding(16.dp),
 ) {
      ...
   }
```

Comment: check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65698101/3585796) answer

Comment: Yes, great explanation. Modifiers are very powerful!