# Why can't the height property of Modifier be written in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I define a `val modifier` with `height(30.dp)`, then I pass it with `modifier.height(5.dp)` to `Spacer` function.

I think the final height of `Spacer` should be 5.dp because I have overwritten the height of `val modifier`.

It seems that the height of Spacer isn't 5.dp, what's wrong with my code?

**Code A**

```
val modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(30.dp)
    
Spacer(modifier = modifier.height(5.dp))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order of `Modifiers` in Composable functions is important.

Refer to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65698101/9636037) and other solutions in the question for more info on this.

---

If you want the height inside the Spacer to be the final one, you have to use `Modifier.then()`.

The given code

```
val modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(30.dp)
Spacer(modifier = modifier.height(5.dp))
```

is same as

```
Spacer(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(30.dp).height(5.dp))
```

But, if you change it using `then()` like this

```
val modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(30.dp)
Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(5.dp).then(modifier))
```

It would become

```
Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(5.dp).fillMaxWidth().height(30.dp))
```

---

**Sample code**

```
@Composable
fun OrderOfModifiers() {
    val modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(30.dp)
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
    ) {
        Spacer(modifier = modifier
            .height(5.dp)
            .background(DarkGray),
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier
            .height(5.dp)
            .then(modifier)
            .background(Cyan),
        )
    }
}
```

**Sample screenshot**

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

When chaining size modifiers such as `Modifier.height(height1).height(height2)` first one is used by design. As in Abhimanyu's answer using `Modifier.then()` doesn't change this either, first one is used. Then changes in which order modifiers are applied.

This approach creates opportunity for developers to assign default size when no modifier with size is set by devs use this Composable. `Slider` is built in similar fashion, it covers full width by default.

When you create a Composable such as

```
@Composable
private fun MyComposable(modifier: Modifier=Modifier){
    Box(modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .size(48.dp))
}
```

And use it as

```
MyComposable(modifier = Modifier.border(3.dp, Color.Green))
```

Will result having a Composable with full screen width and 48.dp height. If you set a Modifier with a size default one gets overridden

```
MyComposable(modifier = Modifier.border(3.dp, Color.Red).size(50.dp))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have tested your code and get the same result, but I'm so strange why `MyComposable(modifier = Modifier.border(3.dp, Color.Red).size(50.dp))` make `fillMaxWidth()` disabled ?

Comment: It's not disabled. When you use `Modifier.width(w1).width(w2).width(w3)`first width Modifier is used. The ones that follow are not taken into consideration unless you use `Modifier.required`. This design approach lets you assign default width if any other size Modifier is assigned. So you can create a Composable with dimensions instead of 0 size when there is no modifier. `Slider` is an example for this. It fills width by default.

Comment: If i don't assign `modifier.fillMaxWidth()` to MyComposable if anyone uses this Composable forgets to assign a Modifier its size would be zero but with a default modifier even if you don't assign a size modifier it would still have a default size. That's a good approach to have default dimensions when there is no other size modifier but when there is you use the one comes from user or developer

Comment: With Modifier.then you might change order from `Modifier.width(w1).width(w2)`to `Modifier.width(w2).width(w1)` but same thing applies first one is used nonetheless. But you change which modifier will be first