# Jetpack compose can't give margin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have to give bottom and start margin to my Box in Compose. As you can see it is not good looking from the photo.[image]

How can I give margin to my bottom element of box. I have tried using .padding both at the end or between elements. Here is my code :

```
 Column {
        Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 32.dp)) {
            Text(text = "Stream", color = Color(255, 87, 34, 255))
            Text(text = "Everywhere", modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 5.dp))
        }
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(160.dp)
                .padding(horizontal = 40.dp)
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.main_movie),
                contentDescription = "Main Movie",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp)),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
            )
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .border(1.dp, color = Color.Gray, shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                    .background(color = Color(35, 35, 35, 65))
                    .align(Alignment.BottomStart)
                    .padding(5.dp)
            ) {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.play_ic),
                    contentDescription = "play_ic",
                    modifier = Modifier.size(30.dp)
                        .padding(5.dp)
                        .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                )
                Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp)) {
                    Text(text = "Continue Watching", color = Color.Gray, fontSize = 10.sp)
                    Text(text = "Ready Player one", color = Color.White, fontSize = 10.sp)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: where do you want the merging to reflect.. could you paste what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I want to do is to margin my rectangle (placed in bottom start (which have items text "Continue Watching" , "Ready Player one"  and one play icon ). the part of code I want to change is :   Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .border(1.dp, color = Color.Gray, shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                    .background(color = Color(35, 35, 35, 65))
                    .align(Alignment.BottomStart)
                    .padding(horizontal = 5.dp , vertical = 10.dp)

Answer (score 1):

```
@Composable
fun Preview() {
    Column {
        Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 32.dp)) {
            Text(text = "Stream", color = Color(255, 87, 34, 255))
            Text(text = "Everywhere", modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 5.dp))
        }
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(160.dp)
                .padding(horizontal = 32.dp),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomStart
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.wallpaper),
                contentDescription = "Main Movie",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp)),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
            )

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(bottom = 8.dp, start = 10.dp)
                    .border(1.dp, color = Color.Gray, shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                    .background(color = Color.Transparent, shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
            ) {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.wallpaper),
                    contentDescription = "play_ic",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(30.dp)
                        .padding(5.dp)
                        .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                )
                Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp)) {
                    Text(text = "Continue Watching", color = Color.Gray, fontSize = 10.sp)
                    Text(text = "Ready Player one", color = Color.White, fontSize = 10.sp)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot , it worked , But I don't know why it does not work with Transparent color. when I do it with your color (Blue) it correctly works.

Comment: Its working with Color.Transparent as well. I'll add a second screenshot as well

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply padding to the Row twice in a specific order:

```
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(5.dp)
                .border(1.dp, color = Color.Gray, shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                .background(color = Color(35, 35, 35, 65))
                .align(Alignment.BottomStart)
                .padding(5.dp)
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.play_ic),
                contentDescription = "play_ic",
                modifier = Modifier.size(30.dp)
                    .padding(5.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
            )
            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp)) {
                Text(text = "Continue Watching", color = Color.Gray, fontSize = 10.sp)
                Text(text = "Ready Player one", color = Color.White, fontSize = 10.sp)
            }
        }
```

Check this answer to read about the order of modifiers https://stackoverflow.com/a/65698101/15884234